# How to remove the filename from the end of the du -h output

Tags: linux, sed, awk

take the example:

```
$ du -h file_size.txt
112K file_size.txt
```

How would i remove the filename from the output of du -h

I have tried to use sed to search for a string (the filename) and replace it with nothing, but it hasnt worked (command below)

```
du -h file_size.txt | sed 's/ 'file_size.txt'//'
```

Could someone please point out why this wont work, or perhaps a better way to do it?

Regards

Paul

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have some bad quoting in that command line.  The simplest is probably:

```
du -h file_size.txt | cut -f -1
```

To fix your command line:

```
du -h file_size.txt | sed 's/file_size.txt//'
```

Since your post has an `awk` tag:

```
du -h file_size.txt | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Comment: or `du -h file_size.txt | sed 's/\s+.*//'`

Comment: @Tomalak has the right idea for using `sed` - sure beats typing the filename twice.

Comment: Woops, the single quotes where a left over of my have a $VARIABLE in there earlier.  Thanks for the help as always

Comment: @paultop6: If you use a variable, instead of opening, closing and re-opening and closing single quotes just use double quotes like this: `sed "s/${VARIABLE}//"`

Comment: @Dennis: Does this work as correctly even if the variable contains regex meta characters?

Comment: By the way, `cut` optionally takes a delimeter (`-d`), which is TAB (`\t`) by default. `du` separates the columns using TAB.

Answer (score 14):

```
du -h file_size.txt | cut -f1
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple output the first column. Here is the awk solution

```
du -h test.txt  | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more verbose, but in any case, this is another way to what you want:

```
du -h file_size.txt |while read x junk; do echo $x; done
```

Answer (score 0):

@OP if your data has distinct fields, for example spaces/tabs, then its easier to use tools like awk/cut to split them on those fields by delimiters. Using regex (eg sed ) is not necessary. Even better is just using the shell.

various ways

```
$ du -h file | awk '{print $1}'
4.0K

$ du -h file | cut -f1
4.0K

$ set -- $(du -h file) #using shell only
$ echo $1
4.0K
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original command would have worked except that you are including a space in the sed regexp, and du outputs tabs.

Answer (score 0):

the output of `du -h` is [tab] delimited.

```
du -h file_size.txt |sed 's/[\t].*//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

To deal with filenames containing newlines:

```
$ du -h $'./filename\nwith\nnewlines.txt' | awk 'NR==1 { print $1 }'
4.0K
```

There's a really cool `sed` solution, using a "print and quit" trick, pulled from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17086464/4812479):

```
$ du -h $'./filename\nwith\nnewlines.txt' | sed -E -n '/(.*)\t.*/{s//\1/p;q;}'
4.0K
```

Most of the other answers on here can't deal with newlines (except for ghostdog's `set` answer):

```
$ du -h $'./filename\nwith\nnewlines.txt' | cut -f1
4.0K
with
newlines.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just `stat` it ?

> ```
>  stat -f '%z' vg1.mp4   # BSD-stat
> ```

```
821258414
```

> ```
> gstat -c '%s' vg1.mp4   # GNU-stat
> ```

```
821258414
```

if u insist on the `du` way, getting first column is cleaner than mentioned :

> ```
> du -smh vg1.mp4 | awk NF=1
> ```

```
783M
```

or the `wc` way - using `<` redirection sends the file over the pipe, so u don't need to trim out the filename —- *somehow BSD-wc pads in an extra space*

> ```
> gwc -c < vg1.mp4    # GNU-wc
> ```

```
821258414
```

> ```
>  wc -c < vg1.mp4    # BSD-wc
> ```

```
 821258414
```