# how can I get sed to quit after the first matching address range?

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file:

```
header
trigger
text1
text2
trigger
text5
trigger
...
trigger
...
```

I want sed to only match between the first two occurrences of 'trigger'. So I tried:

```
sed -n '/trigger/,/trigger/p'
```

But as the man page for sed says, that matches all occurrences within two lines with 'trigger'. I want sed to quit after the first match, so the output would be:

```
trigger
text1
text2
trigger
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use sed to return something from first line which matches and quit early?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773939/how-to-use-sed-to-return-something-from-first-line-which-matches-and-quit-early)

Comment: Not from what I can see. I want to quit after the first address range, not after the first occurrence.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can do this with a loop in GNU `sed`:

```
sed -n '/trigger/{p; :loop n; p; /trigger/q; b loop}'
```

Explanation:

1. When you see the first `/trigger/`, start a block of commands
2. `p` -- print the line
3. `:loop` -- set a label named `loop`
4. `n` -- get the next line
5. `p` -- print the line
6. `/trigger/q` -- if the line matches `/trigger/` then exit `sed`
7. `b` -- jump to `loop`

Answer (score 9):

While jason's ans is what you're looking for, I would have preferred using `awk` for this task

```
awk '/trigger/{p++} p==2{print; exit} p>=1' file
```

Output:

```
trigger
text1
text2
trigger
```

This would provide more flexibility to chose lines between `n`th and `m`the occurrence of `trigger`.

E.g.

```
$ awk -v n=2 -v m=3 '/trigger/{p++} p==m{print; exit} p>=n' file
trigger
text5
trigger
```

Comment: Thanks. In this particular case, I'm actually needing sed because of a bunch of other commands I haven't shown in the question, but I'd definitely find your awk based solution in the general case. And definitely so for flexibility of the n/mth occurence. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Another `awk` variation:

```
awk '/trigger/{f++} f; f>1 {exit}' file
```

- `/trigger/{f++}` if word `trigger` is found increment `f` by `1` (it will be `1` for first time seen and `2` for second time etc)
- `f;` test if `f` is true, if so, do the default action, print the line.
- `f>1 {exit}` if `f` is larger then 1 (it will be 2 at the second hit) exit the program.

Comment: You don't even need the counter... `awk '/trigger/{print $0; exit}'`

Comment: @JasonKohles You are correct :)

Comment: @JasonKohles You do need the counter, otherwise it only prints a single line (the trigger line), then quits.

Comment: @MartinPoelstra That's exactly what the code I was commenting on does

Comment: @JasonKohles The code you were commenting on (i.e. the code in the answer) also prints all lines _between two_ triggers, and then stops when it finds the trigger a second time. Yours only prints the trigger itself, and then immediately stops.