# How can I get content till second match with sed/awk?

Tags: awk, sed

My file:

```
...
str
...
str
...
```

I use:

```
sed '/str/q' myfile
```

This prints:

```
...
str
```

But I need:

```
...
str
...
str
```

How can I get result above? (`...` are other strings.)

Comment: What do you want output if `str` DOESN'T appear twice in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed

```
sed '/str/{x;//q;x;h}' file

...
str
...
str
```

Comment: @kate No problem, if you don't understand anything just ask :)

Comment: This will repeat the line with the first `str` as the last line if a second `str` exists.  Perhaps `sed '/str/{x;//{x;q};x;h}' file` is safer?

Comment: @potong Yes i (possibly wrongly) assumed that str was the entire line. That would be safer though.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the requirements you haven't stated in your question, this MAY be what you want:

```
$ awk '1; /str/&&c++{exit}' file
...
str
...
str
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk '/str/{++i}7;i==2{exit}' file
```

should works for your requirement.

It record the match count in variable `i`, when the count `==2` exit processing.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/str/{:second n; /str/q; b second}' myfile
```

When SED finds the first 'str', starts a loop until the next one is found.

More details here: [SED loop match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20943542/5778960)

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
awk '/str/ && f{print;exit}/str/{f=1}1' f=0 file
```

When /str/ is encountered first time, set a variable to 1 and keep printing. Next time, when encountered, print the line and stop the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, count the matches and exit on the second match. Print other lines.

```
awk 'BEGIN {m=0}; {print}; /str/ {m++; if ( m == 2 ) {  exit; } }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If Perl is an option:

```
perl -pe '$m++ if /str/; exit if $m==2' file
```

Counts the matches.  Exits if matches == 2.