# Reading from A to B, but stop at the first occurrence of B

Tags: string, bash, shell

I'm trying to do a shell script that reads from a file from a string A to a B string. The string A I'm sure that is UNIQUE, but the B string is repeated more than one time.

I'm reading from a file that contains a lot of CREATE queries.

each query ends with (my String B)

> ); ------------------------

String A is composed this way:

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE DBNAME.TABLENAME
```

so I read with sed from A to B

```
sed -n "/$FROMSTR/,/$TOSTR/p" $2 >> querytest.txt
```

I want to stop to the first occurrence of `$TOSTR` (String B)

Comment: And the problem is …?  If A is unique, then what you've got will stop at the first B after A.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, ...stop printing, but not necessarily stop *reading*. If the stop point is 5K into a 2GB file, the difference can be significant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In place of:

```
sed -n "/$FROMSTR/,/$TOSTR/p"
```

use:

```
sed -n "/$FROMSTR/,\${p; /$TOSTR/q}"
```

This prints from the first occurrence of `$FROMSTR` to the last line `$` except that it quits when it sees  the first occurrence of `$TOSTR`.

*Aside:* You should be sure that you trust the source of `FROMSTR` and `TOSTR`.  If either variable contained sed-active characters, the result might not be what you want.

#### Example 1

As a simple example:

```
$ FROMSTR=2; TOSTR=4; seq 10 | sed -n "/$FROMSTR/,\${p; /$TOSTR/q}"
2
3
4
```

#### Example 2

As an exampled closer to your actual input, consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
1
CREATE MULTISET TABLE DBNAME.TABLENAME
2
3
); ------------------------
4
```

And run this command:

```
$ FROMSTR="CREATE MULTISET TABLE DBNAME.TABLENAME"
$ TOSTR="); ------------------------"
$ sed -n "/$FROMSTR/,\${p; /$TOSTR/q}" file
CREATE MULTISET TABLE DBNAME.TABLENAME
2
3
); ------------------------
```

#### Example 3

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
1
CREATE MULTISET TABLE DBNAME.TABLENAME
2
); ------------------------
); ------------------------
3
CREATE MULTISET TABLE DBNAME.TABLENAME
4
); ------------------------
5
```

We define our variables:

```
$ FROMSTR="CREATE MULTISET TABLE DBNAME.TABLENAME"
$ TOSTR="); ------------------------"
```

And, run our code:

```
$ sed -n "/$FROMSTR/,\${p; /$TOSTR/q}" file
CREATE MULTISET TABLE DBNAME.TABLENAME
2
); ------------------------
```

Comment: What are you expecting `$p` to expand to?

Comment: @amphetamachine Good point.  That was eliminated in the update.

Comment: @John1024 It keeps printing all the occurrences, still something missing :/

Comment: @MartinMcFlyDeLuca I just tried it with a more complex sample file (see "Example 3" in the updated answer).  I still show it printing _only_ the first occurrence.  The `q` command causes `sed` to quit as soon as it reaches the first occurrence of `$TOSTR` after the first occurrence of `$FROMSTR`.  Please try _Example 3_ for me and tell me if you see anything different.

Comment: @John1024 first example could not happen, i'm sure that the file is made as create statement then );----- and so on

Comment: @John1024 It prints from $FROMSTR to last occurrence of $TOSTR

Comment: Example3 as well did not work It keeps printing from $FROMSTR to the last occurrence :/

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, seems that sed has some problem in managing escape characters (\r\n)

I changed my $TOSTR to ");"

and used a loop.

```
sed -n "/$FROMSTR/{p; :loop n; p; /$TOSTR/q; b loop}" $2 >> $3
```

then i echo the characters that i need after ");"

```
echo -e "\r\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" >> $3
```

[An useful one on stackoverflow that explain loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943025/how-can-i-get-sed-to-quit-after-the-first-matching-address-range)