# Extracting text between a start and end point in grep - first instance only

Tags: awk, sed, grep

How do I extract text in between strings first instance only.

Source:

```
test66="keyword1"y67h6y7 test66="keyword2"hj67h67j
test66="keyword3"f54fd543f456
```

output:

```
keyword1
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean with "between strings". Try to improve the explanation as well as give some of your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk way
Works for your updated requirements

```
awk '{x=match($0,/test66="([^"]+)"/,a)}x{print a[1];exit}' file
```

sed way

```
sed -n '/test66="\([^"]\+\)".*/{s//\1/p;q}' file
```

They both do pretty much the exact same thing.

1.Search for string

2.Store value inbetween quotes.

3.Print that value

4.Quit

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/test66="\(.*\)"/ {s//\1/p; q}' source.txt
```

Inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17086464/4323

Comment: this does not work correctly for  test66="keyword1" test66="keyword2"

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -m 1 -oP 'test66="\K[^"]*'
```

Output:

```
keyword1
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/test66="/{s//\n/;s/^[^\n]*\n([^"]*)".*/\1/;q}' file
```

Replace the required pattern with a marker i.e. `\n` and remove strings either side of the marker, print and quit.