# 'java' command on windows command prompt cannot run .class file

Tags: cmd, jvm, .class-file

I faced a rather strange problem while executing a java program from the command line on Windows.
I used this command to create a `source.class` file from a `source.java` file.

```
javac source.java
```

After this, I tried to execute the `source.class` file using:

```
java source.class
```

This gave me the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class source.class
```

**However**, when I do this:

```
java source
```

I get the output as desired.
I am curious to know why it failed when I mentioned `.class` **explicitly**. My professor told me that the `java` command is associated with `.class` files. Thus I want to know why this happened. Thank you.

EDIT: I don't believe this is a duplicate. I have already read the linked question. I am asking why the java command cannot execute a file when I mention `.class` **explicitly**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run a Java program from the command line on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line-on-windows)

Comment: just a thought, probably in java's point of view, the argument you passed in is not a filename, it is the class name. That is why the error message is "cannot find the main class", if it treat the argument as filename and append .class itself, the message would probably be "cannot find source.class.class file".

Comment: @Surely what do you mean? the filename and the classname has to be the same. so either way, it's the same.

Comment: just looking around to find some document related. You can test this answer and if it really works in the way, you will know what I meant previously: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2324915/4298881 -- I think the java program would load all the .class file in current directory itself, the argument you provided is only to look for the corresponding class implementation.

Comment: @Surely in reply to your previous comment, I think the appending of '.class' could be it. And thanks, I understand what you mean now.

Comment: @Surely You kind of in a way answered my question. It's not actually the '.class' append that's the thing. The javac makes .class files for each class in the .java file. Hence when I explicitly mention source.class, no such class exists with the name 'source.class' hence I get the error. Thanks.

Comment: @DebanikDawn nice to know it.. don't have java in the machine currently so cannot test it myself  :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152184/discussion-between-debanik-dawn-and-surely).