# Why is it saying that my public class is not defined when I only have one public class and the class file

Tags: drjava

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab6_2{
public static void main(String[] args){
  Scanner sc_1 = new Scanner(System.in);
  int numnber, i;
  System.out.println("Enter an integer between 1 and 10.");
  number = sc_1.nextInt();
 }
}
```

This code is saying "2 errors found:
File: C:\Users\danwr\Downloads\lab 6_2.java  [line: 2]
Error: The public type Lab6_2 must be defined in its own file
File: C:\Users\danwr\Downloads\lab 6_2.java  [line: 7]
Error: number cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: you have a typo 'numnber' this is why you have second error. The first error due to casing in the file name it should be Lab6_2.java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I compile a java file with a different name than the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841847/can-i-compile-a-java-file-with-a-different-name-than-the-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your error message I see two issues.  The first is it appears that your `.java` file is named "lab 6_2.java" (with a space character).  It needs to be named "lab6_2.java".  However, be careful with this - Windows doesn't care that you use "lab" vs. "Lab" but on Unix the file would have to be named "Lab6_2.java".

As for the second error - where is `number` defined? (and is it spelled correctly)?