# Is it possible to use java -cp to run a class which is not in a package

Tags: java

You can use this command to start a jar file and specify a main class.

> java -cp file.jar path.to.MainClass

My problem is that I just have a class that is not contained in a package. So the main class is just called MainClass. So the command becomes

> java -cp file.jar MainClass

The problem is that java does not seem to be able to load the class and just says it could not be found or loaded.
Is there a way to start a jar with the -cp argument like that?

Comment: In general, the syntax you posted is supported and should work. Please give us more information. What does the current directory tree look like? Does `file.jar` exist? What is the only exact error that you see?

Comment: @omajid It says "Fehler: Hauptklasse MainKt konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden" (german), which translates to "Error: Main class MainKt could not be found or loaded". The manifest contains the line "Main-Class: MainKt". Everything works if I start it with "java -jar file.jar".

Comment: Okay. Is the class in the main jar? I understand it's in the current directory? Try `java -cp file.jar:. MainClass`. That is, a classpath that includes both the `file.jar` file and the current director (`.`) separated with a colon (`:`) on Linux. On Windows, use a semicolon (`;`) as the separator instead.

Comment: @omajid it's all in the jar itself. I tried your commands but that didn't change anything.

Comment: @user11227590 There is no problem in running `java -cp file.jar MainClass`, assuming the `file.jar` file exists and it contains a `MainClass.class` file in it on the root level of the jar. Please [edit] your question to include the source code of the `MainClass` file and the content of the `.jar` file with `jar -tf file.jar`. Also show how you have compiled the java source code and have built the jar file.

Comment: @omajid OOOOOOPS I really accidentally made a capitalization mistake while doing this. I feel so stupid right now... The file was called MainClass and the class was just Mainclass without the capital C. I got it confused. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

Just run:

```
java -cp file.jar MainKt
```

`Main-Class` in manifest only impacts `java -cp file.jar`, not when used with a class argument like `MainClass` (which presumably doesn't exist) or `MainKt`.

Also, if your class is really named `MainClass` inside the `MainKt.java` source file, it should be renamed to match the source file name (or vice versa) first; see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841847/can-i-compile-a-java-file-with-a-different-name-than-the-class).

Comment: It was really just a capitalization mistake on my end. Sorry