# Find, replace, and increment at each occurence of string

Tags: bash, replace, sed, increment, bioinformatics

I'm relatively new to scripting and apologize in advance for this painfully simple problem.  I believe I've searched pretty thoroughly, but apparently no other answers or cookbooks have been explicit enough for me to understand (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file) - still couldn't get it).

I have a file that is made up of strings of letters (DNA, if you care), one string per line.  Above each string I've inserted another line to identify the underlying string.  For those of you who are bioinformaticians, I'm trying to make up a test data set in fasta format, maybe you have tools?  Anyway, I'd put a distinct word, "num", after each ">" with the intention of using a bash incrementer and sed to create a unique number heading each string. For example, in data.txt, I have...

> >num, blah, blah, blah
>
> ATCGACTGAATCGA
>
> >num, blah, blah, blah
>
> ATCGATCGATCGATCG
>
> >num, blah, blah, blah
>
> ATCGATCGATCGATCG

I would like it to be...

> >0, blah, blah, blah
>
> ATCGACTGAATCGA
>
> >1, blah, blah, blah
>
> ATCGATCGATCGATCG
>
> >2, blah, blah, blah
>
> ATCGATCGATCGATCG

The solution can be in any language as long as it's complete && gets the job done.  I have a little experience with sed, awk, bash, and c++ (little == slightly more than no experience).  I know, I know, I need to learn perl, but I've only just started.  The question is this: How to replace "num" with a number that increments on each replacement? It doesn't matter if the underlying string is identical to another somewhere else. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Totally (pseudo) off-topic, but please checkout [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries).

Comment: For instance, [Genetic programming](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries/Genetic_programming).

Comment: Sed is not the tool to use here. You can't combine sed and bash in the way you want. It would be easier to write an editor macro in Emacs or Vim than to do it in sed+bash. (Awk would work, though.) As I said, even a real editor would work. You need to explore some tools and start learning them. Almost anything will be better than nothing. -- You probably wrote out all the "num" lines by hand, too, right?

Comment: @Jared, thanks I'll look into Haskell.  @yam655, Good to know that I can't use sed and bash this way.  I just started using Vim last week and so far I like it a lot better than pico or nano :).  Give me a little credit here, I used awk to insert the 40,000 lines, I guess you can call that "by hand".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
perl -ple 's/num/$n++/e' filename
```

dry run 1st, if it is do that, what you want

Comment: Worked perfectly! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

This uses process substitution, which may or may not be available on your system.

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ exec 3< <(cat test.txt)
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ i=0
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ while read -u 3 first_word the_rest; do
 if [ "$first_word" == ">num," ]; then
 echo ">$i," $the_rest; i=$((i + 1)); else
 echo $first_word $the_rest; fi; done
>0, blah, blah, blah

ATCGACTGAATCGA

>1, blah, blah, blah

ATCGATCGATCGATCG

>2, blah, blah, blah

ATCGATCGATCGATCG
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, too, and thanks for your answer!  It seemed like it ran a tiny bit slower than the perl line above, but I find this a very interesting way to get the job done! I didn't know (but guess I should have) that you could do so much from the command line.  Does it maintain the i=0 only until you run the following command? I'd vote you up if I could, but I don't have enough reputation yet (this was my first post).  Thanks again!

Comment: i starts off as 0, but it increments with i=$((i + 1)), and whatever it is after the loop, it remains, until set to another value or unset.

Comment: Cool! This stuff is great. On a side note: your life seems cool.  Keep it up and good luck!