# How to replace text with a regex pattern and integrate a counter in the replacement text?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, counter, preg-replace-callback

```
function parse($string){
    $counter = 0;
    
    $string = preg_replace("_\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]_si", '<span class="b">'. $counter .'. $1</span>', $string, -1, $counter);
    
    return $string;
}
```

I'm trying to make a ubb parser, that parses tags and put the counting in front of it:

```
[b]Hey[/b]
[b]Hello[/b]
```

Should return this:

```
<span class="b">1. Hey</span>
<span class="b">2. Hello</span>
```

But is returning this:

```
<span class="b">1. Hey</span>
<span class="b">1. Hello</span>
```

So beside the function above, I've tried this:

```
function parse($string){
    
    $counter = 0;
    
    $string = preg_replace_callback(("_\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]_si", function(){
        '<span class="b">'. $counter++ .'. $1</span>',
    }, $string);
}
```

but that, and the function at the top, didn't work. What am I doing wrong and/or could I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually solved it with the help of TiMESPLiNTER (give him the credit!), didn't know `$1` didn't get brought along and that you have to call a variable `$matches` in the callback function and get `$matches[1]` instead of $1.

```
$counter = 1;

function parse(){
    function cb($matches){
        global $counter;

        return '<span class="b">'. $this->counter .'. ' . $matches[1] . '</span>';
    }

    $string = preg_replace_callback("_\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]_si", 'cb', $string);
}
```

Comment: Don't know it this is a good solution and will work if `register_globals` is set to `off`. (Just guessing)

Comment: Then it's time to start ;-).

Comment: Undefined variable `$string`. I don't believe `$this->counter` is right either.  And `parse()` doesn't print or `return` anything.

Answer (score 3):

I would solve it with a small class with the counter as property and the *callback* is a method of the class.

```
class Increaser {
    private $counter;

    public function replace($string) {
        $this->counter = 0;

        return preg_replace_callback("_\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]_si", array($this, 'createReplacement'), $string);
    }

    private function createReplacement($matches) {
        ++$this->counter;

        return '<span class="b">'. $this->counter .'. ' . $matches[1] . '</span>';
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of having a class?

Comment: Your counter will count. Don't know if it's the best solution but only one I can mention.

Comment: Your*. ;) 

Using global variables, counting has worked with `preg_replace_callback`, but it would display `$1` instead of the actual value.

Comment: Oops ;-) I'm not native speaker so I mess this things up sometimes in speedy typing. Corrected it. The function to do the replacement gets an arg. Look at edited code in my answer.

Comment: Got one more `(` than you need after `callback` :)

Comment: See the answer I just posted. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare a `global` "counter" variable or design a class-based workaround.  You can simply use a static variable declaration inside of `preg_replace_callback()`'s custom function.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/viKP9)) -- this is the way I would code my own project

```
$ubbText = <<<TEXT
[b]Hey[/b]
[b]Hello[/b]
TEXT;

echo preg_replace_callback(
         "~\[b](.*?)\[/b]~si",
         function ($m) {
             static $counter = 0;
             return '<span class="b">' . (++$counter) . '. ' . $m[1] . '</span>';
         },
         $ubbText
     );
```

---

Alternatively, you could avoid the use of a `static` declaration and use `preg_replace()` because your code logic will not possibly replace replacements (an infinite loop is not possible).  To be honest, I don't prefer this technique because it involves iterated `preg_` function calls which make one replacement per iteration and the regex engine will need to restart from the beginning of the input string each time.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BXTI0))

```
$counter = 0;
do {
    $ubbText = preg_replace(
        "~\[b](.*?)\[/b]~si",
        '<span class="b">' . (++$counter) . '. $1</span>',
         $ubbText,
         1,
         $count
     );
} while ($count);
echo $ubbText;
```

Output (from both snippets):

```
<span class="b">1. Hey</span>
<span class="b">2. Hello</span>
```

p.s. I suppose I should state for the record that your regex pattern will not favorably handle the possibility of nested tags `[b] bold [b]re-bold[/b][/b]`.  If these types of occurrences are not possible in your application's text, then no worries.  There are ways to mitigate this vulnerability, but I will not digress in this post.  Search Stack Overflow for this if your application requires it.