# Replace character of a particular line with incremental number per line

Tags: php

I have a text file (`data.txt`) with the following lines

```
# one
# two
a-two
b-two
c-two
# three
a-three
b-three
# four
```

I would like to replace # with incremental number per line so to be like this

```
1 one
2 two
a-two
b-two
c-two
3 three
a-three
b-three
4 four
```

I have try to do this

```
    <?php
    $path_to_file = 'data.txt';
    $what_to_replace = '#';
    $i = 0; // initial count
    
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
    $file_contents = str_replace($what_to_replace, $i++,$file_contents);
    file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
    ?>
```

it did changed in all lines with `#` but not incrementally

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273066/find-a-specific-string-and-replace-it-with-an-increment-php

Comment: @GiacomoM that was helpful, based on the answers there i will try to rewrite a code to fit with my needs ~ thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64964297/2943403

Comment: @Reham Implementation of my recommended technique from the dupe target: https://3v4l.org/VYnFH

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple way via `preg_replace_callback()`:

```
$i = 1;
$file_contents = preg_replace_callback('/^#/m', function($match) use (&$i) {
    return $i++;
}, $file_contents);
```

The `m` (multiline) flag is important - it will force our pattern to match `#` at the start of *any* line, not just the first.

Comment: `(\w+)` is not necessary

Comment: Extra clarity certainly doesn't hurt

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to iterate over all the lines and replace the hash one by one. Of course, you can use some preg_replace as well to only replace the # at the line beginning: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

```
$result = '';
$handle = fopen("data.txt", "r");
$i = 1;
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $content .= str_replace('#', $i++,$line) . "\n";
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}

file_put_contents('data.txt', $result);
```

Comment: This risks replacing all `#` in a line.  It is unaware of the location of the `#` and has no means to limit the number of replacements it makes in a line.  While this may work for the sample input, it is not suitable for general use cases.

Answer (score 1):

We can split the text line-by-line, then process each line individually, looking for a `#` at the start of the line & modifying the output in those cases.
The `preg_replace_callback` approach is better than this one, IMO.

```php
$text = file_get_contents(...);
$lines = explode("\n", $text); // split by unix-style line break 
$out = []; // For storing the modified lines
$i=0;
foreach ($lines as $line){
    if (substr($line,0,1)=='#'){
        //replace the first character & increment the counter if line starts with #
        $i++;
        $line = $i.substr($line,1);
    }
    //append the SOMETIMES modified line to the output
    $out[] = $line;
}
// convert array of lines to string
$fixedText = implode("\n", $out);
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28725803/802469 for a more robust version of the `explode("\n", $text)` line.

Personally, I like the `$out = []; ...; implode(...)` approach. I find it easier to work with & to visualize in my mind. Using an `$out = ""; $out .= $line."\n";` approach would work just as well. I suspect any performance increase from going with string would be negligible, but might lower your carbon footprint a small amount.

If you have serious performance/resource concerns (extremely large files) then the `fopen()/while fgets()` approach would be better, and `fopen/fwrite()` could be used to append each output line to a file without using up memory for an output string.

Comment: @mickmackusa, I absolutely agree. Thanks for pointing it out. :) Iiii think I was feeling a bit lazy by the time I was done with the code snippet lol. Updated it now!

Answer (score 1):

```
$path_to_file = 'data.txt';
$what_to_replace = '#';
$i = 1; // initial count

$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $file_contents);
$new_lines = [];

foreach ($lines as $line) {
  if (strpos($line, '#') !== false) {
    $new_lines[] = str_replace('#', $i, $line);
    $i++;
  } else {
    $new_lines[] = $line;
  }
}

file_put_contents($path_to_file, implode(PHP_EOL, $new_lines));
```

Comment: This risks replacing all `#` in a qualifying line.  It is has no means to limit the number of replacements it makes in a line.  While this may work for the sample input, it is not suitable for general use cases.  This answer is missing its educational explanation.  I would not use this snippet in my own project because it is making multiple iterated function calls and declares a temporary array before producing the mutated string -- it's just too indirect for my tastes.

Comment: Yeah man lol no argument here