# Are there any ways in Bash to insert a paragraph before the matched pattern?

Tags: bash

Sorry but I am still stuck on this problem.
I would like to insert a paragraph before the first match of `"<tr>                                  <td nowrap valign="top"/paragraph"`

So I use this code:

```
sed '0,/<tr>                                  <td nowrap valign="top"/ { s/<tr>                                  <td nowrap valign="top"/paragraph\nsd/g }' /var/www/html/INFOSEC/english/news/test.html
```

However, the program returns me the whole page of that HTML file and no insertion happens.

Also, I would like to insert some values in the variable in sed code; can I do that?

```
eg. sed -i 's/old/$new/g' file
```

Comment: please answer instead of edit. Thanks for anyone who help. Is it an answer??? sorry i carelessly roll back it

Comment: @ahmet you are a trip! next time I come to Seattle area, I wanna buy you a beer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To insert before a pattern, you have to make sure your pattern matches something in the file.

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/usr/src/clusterFix$ cat test.html
<tr> <td nowrap valign="top">blather blather blather</td></tr>
jcomeau@intrepid:/usr/src/clusterFix$ sed  '/<tr> *<td nowrap valign="top"/i<p>this is a new paragraph</p>' test.html
<p>this is a new paragraph</p>
<tr> <td nowrap valign="top">blather blather blather</td></tr>
```

The "*" above matches any amount of spaces. Maybe that is what's causing your command to fail. Of course you need the "-i" switch if you want to edit the file in-place.

For the second question, `sed -i 's/old/$new/g' file`, that is almost right except you need to use double-quotes (`"`) instead of single-quotes (`'`) in order for string interpolation to work: `sed -i "s/old/$new/g" file`

See http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq4_004.html from [How to use sed to replace only the first occurrence in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file) for syntax on replacing only the first match.

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ cat test.txt 
this is not the test
this is not the test
this is a test
this is a test
this is a test
this is a test
this is a test
this is a test
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ sed '0,/\(this is a test\)/s//before first match\n\1/' test.txt
this is not the test
this is not the test
before first match
this is a test
this is a test
this is a test
this is a test
this is a test
this is a test
```

Comment: Thanks can i use this add some xml tag by using sed just like this???

sed '0,/<item pop="N">/ { /<item pop="N">/<item pop="N">\n<title>aaa<\/title>\n<guid>ccc<\/guid>\n<link>ddd<\/link>\n<description><![CDATA[<p>dsfsd<\/p>]]><\/description>\n<\/item>\n }' /var/www/html/INFOSEC/english/rss/test.xml

Comment: probably not. do you know what the '0,/pattern/' does? it matches everything between the start of the file and the pattern. and what are you doing with the curly braces "{}"?

Comment: so how can i modify html/xml tag with sed??? all < > change to lt; something???thanks your help

Comment: you can use it, just learn the syntax. you seem to be making it more complicated than it really is.

Comment: the braces there is that i want to insert before ONLY THE FIRST match.

sed -i '0,/<tr>*<td nowrap valign="top"/ { s/<tr>*<td nowrap valign="top"/paragraph\nsd/ }' /var/www/html/INFOSEC/english/news/test.html

i tried this but it still not works :(

Comment: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq4_004.html from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file

Comment: yup the reference is helpful,  how about insert before the first match? thx

Comment: see edited answer. I've never used this syntax before, I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: yeah it somehow works but it replace my orginal text (eg this is a test)

Comment: oops, my bad. fixed, see revised answer.

Comment: thx i use another stupid way which replace the old string with some new thing plus old string