# sed to change string in a file only once

Tags: bash, sed, command-line-interface

suggest I have a file `example` as follows:

```
c
a
b
a
b
d
```

and I want to change the first occurance of `a` to `e`. Then I do this:

```
sed -i 's/a/e/' example
```

and all `a` changed to `e`.

So is there any way to make sed only replace once within a file?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Applying the information from Aziz' duplicate link to your question, I think this will give you the desired result for your case:

```
sed -i '0,/a/s//e/' example
```

Comment: For greater readability, this could be written `sed -i 0,/a/ s/a/e/'`

Answer (score 6):

> Applying the information from Aziz' duplicate link to your question, I
>   think this will give you the desired result for your case:
>
> ```
> sed -i '0,/a/s//e/' example
> ```

Rabe's answer is good.
But, adding a space between address range and 's' command makes it more clearer.
like this:

```
sed -i '0,/a/ s//e/' example
```

And Wilson's version seems redundant.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -i '0,/needle/ s|needle|replacement|'` file.txt

The first section matches the occurrence of the needle. After the space, then it goes to work on the replacement for that occurrence.

Personally, I think it's more readable to show the needle twice. The `//` in other answers is a shorthand where sed remembers the first needle.

I assume the first section matches the whole line, or just the text leading up to the match. And then I suppose you could search for something different to replace on that line. But I haven't tested this variation yet.

Notice I changed the delimiter to |. If the replacement text had slashes, changing the delimiter is easier.