# sed insert after ONLY the first line match?

Tags: unix, sed

Trying to do this:

```
sed -e '/^MatchMeOnce/i\
MATCHED'
```

on the example text:

```
Line1
Line2
MatchMeOnce
Line4
MatchMeOnce
Line6
```

How can I get it to only match the very first record occurrence and to **not** match on subsequent lines?

```
Line1
Line2
MATCHED
Line4
MatchMeOnce
Line6
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use sed to replace only the first occurrence in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file)

Answer (score 7):

This might work for you:

```
sed '1,/MatchMeOnce/s//MATCHED/' file
```

This will work for all variations of sed as long as `MatcMeOnce` is on the 2nd line or greater, or this (GNU sed):

```
sed '0,/MatchMeOnce/s//MATCHED/'  file
```

which caters for above edge condition:

Or another alternative (all sed's) which *slurps* the entire file into memory:

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/MatchMeOnce/MATCHED/' file
```

which has the added advantage in that if you want to choose the nth rather than the 1st of `MatchMeOnce` all you need do is change the occurrence flag i.e. to change the second occurrence:

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/MatchMeOnce/MATCHED/2' file
```

To change the last occurrence use:

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\(.*)MatchMeOnce/\1MATCHED/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed` (not so obvious):

```
sed '1,/^MatchMeOnce$/ {/^$/\c
MATCHED
}'
```

`awk` (obvious):

```
BEGIN {
    matched = 0
}
/^MatchMeOnce$/ {
    if (matched == 0) {
        print "MATCHED"
        matched = 1
        next
    }
}
{ print }
```

`perl` is also cool...

Hope it more or less works :-)

Answer (score 1):

GNU sed has the `t` command to branch to end of script (alternatively a given label) when any substitution matches.

Personally I use `perl -ne` and `perl -ane` (and I suppose some people use Ruby) unless the awk or sed solution is blindingly obvious. But I realize it's still possible for some systems to have awk and sed without Perl and to make it difficult to install Perl; and that some programmers prefer awk and sed regardless.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed '/MatchMeOnce/{s//MATCHED/;:a;n;ba}' input.txt
Line1
Line2
MATCHED
Line4
MatchMeOnce
Line6
```