# sed to insert on first match only

Tags: linux, bash, sed

UPDATED:

Using sed, how can I insert (NOT SUBSTITUTE) a new line on only the first match of keyword for each file.

Currently I have the following but this inserts for every line containing Matched Keyword and I want it to only insert the New Inserted Line for only the first match found in the file:

```
sed -ie '/Matched Keyword/ i\New Inserted Line' *.*
```

For example:

Myfile.txt:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
This line contains the Matched Keyword and other stuff
Line 4
This line contains the Matched Keyword and other stuff
Line 6
```

changed to:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
New Inserted Line
This line contains the Matched Keyword and other stuff
Line 4
This line contains the Matched Keyword and other stuff
Line 6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/148451/1086804) - you may be able to adapt it by using newline and backreferences. See also [this sed guide](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq4_004.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use sed to replace only the first occurrence in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want one with sed*:

```
sed '0,/Matched Keyword/s//Matched Keyword\nNew Inserted Line/' myfile.txt
```

*only works with GNU sed

Comment: This doesn't do anything for me at all.

Comment: Ah, your solution is apparently specific to GNU sed.  Though it's still wrong, alas.

Comment: Works for me with `GNU sed version 4.2.1`. @Squazic, maybe you want to qualify your answer. Good luck to all.

Comment: This worked for me.  I just swapped the Matched Keyword with the New Inserted Line since I wanted the insertion to occur before the Matched Keyword.  Thanks everyone for your inputs.

Answer (score 22):

You can sort of do this in GNU sed:

```
sed '0,/Matched Keyword/s//New Inserted Line\n&/'
```

But it's not portable.  Since portability is good, here it is in awk:

```
awk '/Matched Keyword/ && !x {print "Text line to insert"; x=1} 1' inputFile
```

Or, if you want to pass a variable to print:

```
awk -v "var=$var" '/Matched Keyword/ && !x {print var; x=1} 1' inputFile
```

These both insert the text line *before* the first occurrence of the keyword, on a line by itself, per your example.

Remember that with both sed and awk, the matched keyword is a regular expression, not just a keyword.

**UPDATE:**

Since this question is also tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), here's a simple solution that is pure bash and doesn't required sed:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=0
while read line; do
  if [[ "$line" =~ 'Matched Keyword' && $n = 0 ]]; then
    echo "New Inserted Line"
    n=1
  fi
  echo "$line"
done
```

As it stands, this as a pipe.  You can easily wrap it in something that acts on files instead.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this in traditional sed?

Comment: It may be possible to adapt potong's solution for non-GNU sed.  But it won't be a one-liner.  I generally only do sed one-liners.  :-)

Comment: @Velthune - not at all, that's an excellent addition. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 9):

This might work for you:

```
sed -i -e '/Matched Keyword/{i\New Inserted Line' -e ':a;n;ba}' file
```

You're nearly there! Just create a loop to read from the `Matched Keyword` to the end of the file.

After inserting a line, the remainder of the file can be printed out by:

1. Introducing a loop place holder `:a` (here `a` is an arbitrary name).
2. Print the current line and fetch the next into the pattern space with the `n`command.
3. Redirect control back using the `ba` command which is essentially a `goto` to the `a` place holder. The end-of-file condition is naturally taken care of by the `n` command which terminates any further sed commands if it tries to read passed the end-of-file.

With a little help from bash, a true one liner can be achieved:

```
sed $'/Matched Keyword/{iNew Inserted Line\n:a;n;ba}' file
```

Alternative:

```
sed 'x;/./{x;b};x;/Matched Keyword/h;//iNew Inserted Line' file
```

This uses the `Matched Keyword` as a flag in the hold space and once it has been set any processing is curtailed by bailing out immediately.

Comment: ummm, yea, can you give a fully working example as I'm not sure how to create this "loop" in a sed oneline expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append a line after first match only, use AWK instead of SED as below

```
awk '{print} /Matched Keyword/ && !n {print "New Inserted Line"; n++}' myfile.txt
```

Output:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
This line contains the Matched Keyword and other stuff
New Inserted Line
Line 4
This line contains the Matched Keyword and other stuff
Line 6
```

Comment: and how do you do that in place?