# Bash: add multiple lines after a first occurene of matched pattern in the file

Tags: bash, sed, awk

How to acheive this with awk/sed?

Input:

```
zero
one
two
three
four
```

output:

```
zero
one
    one-one
    one-two
    one-three
two
three
four
```

Note: I need actual tab to be included in the new lines to be added.

Comment: It's rather straight-forward.  `\n\t`???

Comment: Your example I/O does not imply a well-defined algorithm.

Comment: Is the fact that each of your added lines starts with "one" in any way related to the fact that the line you're searching for starts with "one"?

Answer (score 4):

With [GNU sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html), you can use the [a\](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Appending-text-after-a-line-128)  command to append lines after a match (or `i\` to insert lines before a match.

```
sed '/one/a\ \tone-one\n\tone-two\n\tone-three' file 
zero
one
    one-one
    one-two
    one-three
two
three
four
```

Answer (score 2):

The title states 'after the first occurrence' (I presume occurene is a typo), however, other answers don't seem to cater this requirement and due to the unique nature of the sample set, it is not that obvious when you test.

If we change the sample set to

```
zero
one
three
one
four
five
one
six
seven
one
```

Then we would need something like `awk '/one/ && !x {print $0; print "\tone-one\n\tone-two\n\tone-three"; x=1;next} 1'`, which produces

```
zero
one
    one-one
    one-two
    one-three
    two
three
one
four
five
one
six
seven
one
```

Actually, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9970590/2370920) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22497489/2370920) answers provide some more options as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk '1; /one/{print "\n\tone-one\n\tone-two\n\tone-three"}' file
zero
one
        one-one
        one-two
        one-three
two
three
four
```

Comment: `'1; /one/ {print "..."}'` would have worked as well (without the need for next).

Comment: @EtanReisner: That would have printed `one` twice.

Comment: Not if you didn't include `$0` in your print.

Comment: This inserts after _every_ occurrence, not just the requested _first_ occurrence.

Comment: Nope it inserts after `one` text only.