# Insert multiple lines into a file after specified pattern using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I want to insert multiple lines into a file using shell script.
Let us consider my input file contents are:
**input.txt:**

```
abcd
accd
cdef
line
web
```

Now I have to insert four lines after the line 'cdef' in the **input.txt** file.
After inserting my file should change like this:

```
abcd
accd
cdef
line1
line2
line3
line4
line
web
```

The above insertion I should do using the shell script. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Another `sed`,

```
sed '/cdef/r add.txt' input.txt
```

input.txt:

```
abcd
accd
cdef
line
web
```

add.txt:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

**Test:**

```
sat:~# sed '/cdef/r add.txt' input.txt
abcd
accd
cdef
line1
line2
line3
line4
line
web
```

If you want to apply the changes in `input.txt` file. Then, use `-i` with `sed`.

```
sed -i '/cdef/r add.txt' input.txt
```

If you want to use a regex as an expression you have to use the `-E` tag with `sed`.

```
sed -E '/RegexPattern/r add.txt' input.txt
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this the other way around (remove text found in add.txt from input.txt) ?

Comment: A variation, that allows for an anonymous file is to pipe a here document into a sed invocation and use the `r` command to read from `/dev/stdin`.

Comment: Hi, is there a quick way to add 4 spaces before the added lines from `add.txt` ?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if you have 100 occurrences of `cdef` in the file, it will paste `add.txt` contents into your file 100 times as well :(

Answer (score 53):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
sed "/cdef/aline1\nline2\nline3\nline4" input.txt
```

If you started with:

```
abcd
accd
cdef
line
web
```

this would produce:

```
abcd
accd
cdef
line1
line2
line3
line4
line
web
```

If you want to save the changes to the file in-place, say:

```
sed -i "/cdef/aline1\nline2\nline3\nline4" input.txt
```

Comment: I am new to `sed` but wow I am in love with its power! If you want to append an empty newline *first* you have to escape the backslash character after the append command like this : `sed "/cdef/a\\\nline1\nline2\nline3\nline4" input.txt`. I am not sure why it works like that though, if somebody could explain this would be nice!

Comment: The current command inserts the line* on every mention of `cdef`, is there a way to make it so that it only inserts on the first time it encounters `cdef` and no more?

Comment: MacOS `sed` doesn't implement the `a` command precisely the same as GNU `sed`, so the above won't work in MacOS without mods - at least as of macOS 10.13 ( see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131940/230763 )

Comment: MacOS `sed` also doesn't treat the `-i` option the same as GNU `sed`. On MacOS, `-i` requires an argument with a backup suffix. You would want to specify `-i ''`.

Answer (score 32):

```
sed '/^cdef$/r'<(
    echo "line1"
    echo "line2"
    echo "line3"
    echo "line4"
) -i -- input.txt
```

Comment: Missed this good answer. Shorter but less readable is `sed '/^cdef$/r' <(printf "%s\n" line{1..4}) -i -- input.txt`.

Comment: Note that this won't work in containers when you're issuing the command from the host, as the file descriptor from `<(...)` will be created on the host and not the guest. Using the `/someline/a<added\ncontent>` method works better, especially if you do something like `sed "/someline/a$(echo 'here you can have newlines' | tr \\n @ | sed '\''s/@/\\n/g'\')" -i -- input.txt` (not a full example and not properly tested, I don't have time for it now, but this should include the building blocks for what you need).

Answer (score 19):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/cdef/{print $0 RS "line1" RS "line2" RS "line3" RS "line4";next}1' input.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- You find the line you want to insert from using `/.../`
- You print the current line using `print $0`
- `RS` is built-in `awk` variable that is by default set to `new-line`.
- You add new lines separated by this variable
- `1` at the end results in printing of every other lines. Using `next` before it allows us to prevent the current line since you have already printed it using `print $0`.

```
$ awk '/cdef/{print $0 RS "line1" RS "line2" RS "line3" RS "line4";next}1' input.txt
abcd
accd
cdef
line1
line2
line3
line4
line
web
```

To make changes to the file you can do:

```
awk '...' input.txt > tmp && mv tmp input.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a more generic solution based on @rindeal [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51585664/12016)  which does not work on MacOS/BSD (`/r` expects a file):

```sh
cat << DOC > input.txt
abc
cdef
line
DOC
```

```
$ cat << EOF | sed '/^cdef$/ r /dev/stdin' input.txt
line 1
line 2
EOF

# outputs:
abc
cdef
line 1
line 2
line
```

This can be used to pipe anything into the file at the given position:

```sh
$ date | sed '/^cdef$/ r /dev/stdin' input.txt

# outputs
abc
cdef
Tue Mar 17 10:50:15 CET 2020
line
```

Also, you could add multiple commands which allows deleting the marker line `cdef`:

```sh
$ date | sed '/^cdef$/ {
  r /dev/stdin
  d
}' input.txt

# outputs
abc
Tue Mar 17 10:53:53 CET 2020
line
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` for inserting output of some command in the middle of `input.txt`.
The lines to be inserted can be the output of a `cat otherfile`, `ls -l` or 4 lines with a number generated by `printf`.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0;next}
    {print}
    /cdef/ {for (i=1; i <= length(a); i++) { print a[i] }}'
    <(printf "%s\n" line{1..4}) input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is easy to understand

- Copy before the pattern
- Add your lines
- Copy after the pattern
- Replace original file

  FILENAME='app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php'

#### STEP 1 copy until the pattern

```
sed '/THEPATTERNYOUARELOOKINGFOR/Q' $FILENAME >>${FILENAME}_temp
```

#### STEP 2 add your lines

```
cat << 'EOL' >> ${FILENAME}_temp

HERE YOU COPY AND
PASTE MULTIPLE
LINES, ALSO YOU CAN
//WRITE COMMENTS

AND NEW LINES
AND SPECIAL CHARS LIKE $THISONE

EOL
```

#### STEP 3 add the rest of the file

```
grep -A 9999 'THEPATTERNYOUARELOOKINGFOR' $FILENAME >>${FILENAME}_temp
```

#### REPLACE original file

```
mv ${FILENAME}_temp $FILENAME
```

## if you need variables, in step 2 replace 'EOL' with EOL

```
cat << EOL >> ${FILENAME}_temp

this variable will expand: $variable1

EOL
```

Comment: <h1>there is no need to scream</h1>

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have a file called 'insert.txt' containing the lines you want to add:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

If the PATTERN 'cdef' REPEATS MULTIPLE TIMES in your input.txt file, and you want to add the lines from 'insert.txt' after ALL occurrences of the pattern 'cdef' , then a easy solution is:

`sed -i -e '/cdef/r insert.txt' input.txt`

but, if the PATTERN 'cdef' REPEATS MULTIPLE TIMES in your input.txt file, and you want to add the lines from 'insert.txt' ONLY AFTER THE FIRST OCCURRENCE of the pattern, a beautiful solution is:

`printf "%s\n" "/cdef/r insert.txt" w | ed -s input.txt`

Both solution will work fine in case the pattern happens only once in your input.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @rindeal [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51585664/12016) but with better readability of the input

```
sed '/^cdef$/r'<(cat <<EOF
line1
line2
line3
line4
EOF
) -i -- input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting the content over the 4th line (like you want)

```
sed -i "4i line1\nline2\nline3\nline4" input.txt
```

If you don't want to save the changes to the file in-place, remove "-i" :

```
sed "4i line1\nline2\nline3\nline4" input.txt
```

Using sed by GNU*

If you started input.txt with:

```
abcd
accd
cdef
line
web
```

this would produce:

```
abcd
accd
cdef
line1
line2
line3
line4
line
web
```

Answer (score -1):

I needed to template a few files with minimal tooling and for me the issue with above `sed -e '/../r file.txt` is that it only appends the file after it prints out the rest of the match, it doesn't replace it.

This doesn't do it (all matches are replaced and pattern matching continues from same point)

```
#!/bin/bash

TEMPDIR=$(mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/}$(basename $0).XXXXXXXXXXXX")
# remove on exit
trap "rm -rf $TEMPDIR" EXIT

DCTEMPLATE=$TEMPDIR/dctemplate.txt
DCTEMPFILE=$TEMPDIR/dctempfile.txt

# template that will replace
printf "0replacement
1${SHELL} data
2anotherlinenoEOL" > $DCTEMPLATE

# test data
echo -e "xxy \n987 \nxx xx\n yz yxxyy" > $DCTEMPFILE

# print original for debug
echo "---8<--- $DCTEMPFILE"
cat $DCTEMPFILE
echo "---8<--- $DCTEMPLATE"
cat $DCTEMPLATE
echo "---8<---"

# replace 'xx' -> contents of $DCTEMPFILE
perl -e "our \$fname = '${DCTEMPLATE}';" -pe 's/xx/`cat $fname`/eg' ${DCTEMPFILE}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to do that with a bash script, that's useful.

```
echo $password | echo 'net.ipv4.ping_group_range=0 2147483647' |  sudo -S tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your command to help the future readers understand what has been done?