# Insert multiple lines of text before specific line using Bash

Tags: bash, unix, sed, text-manipulation

I am trying to insert a few lines of text before a specific line, but keep getting sed errors when I try to add a new line character.  My command looks like:

```
sed -r -i '/Line to insert after/ i Line one to insert \\
    second new line to insert \\
    third new line to insert' /etc/directory/somefile.txt
```

The error that is reported is:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 77: unterminated `s' command
```

I've tried, using `\n`, `\\` (as in the example), no character at all, just moving the second line to the next line.  I've also tried something like:

```
sed -r -i -e '/Line to insert after/ i Line one to insert'
    -e 'second new line to insert'
    -e 'third new line to insert' /etc/directory/somefile.txt
```

EDIT!: Apologies, I wanted the text inserted BEFORE the existing, not after!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed -i '/Line to insert after/ i Line one to insert \
second new line to insert \
third new line to insert' file
```

Comment: Probably want to use `a` if you are inserting after

Comment: Superb guide. Thanks a lot @anubhava

Comment: Is there any way we can insert multiple lines written in a seperate file into our file? A suggestion like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22497499/4428377) .

Answer (score 8):

For anything other than simple substitutions on individual lines, use awk instead of sed for simplicity, clarity, robustness, etc., etc.

To insert before a line:

```
awk '
/Line to insert before/ {
    print "Line one to insert"
    print "second new line to insert"
    print "third new line to insert"
}
{ print }
' /etc/directory/somefile.txt
```

To insert after a line:

```
awk '
{ print }
/Line to insert after/ {
    print "Line one to insert"
    print "second new line to insert"
    print "third new line to insert"
}
' /etc/directory/somefile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

On MacOs I needed a few more things.

- Double backslash after the `i`
- Empty quotes after the `-i` to specify no backup file
- Leading backslashes to add leading whitespace
- Trailing double backslashes to add newlines

This code searches for the first instance of `</plugins` in pom.xml and inserts another XML object immediately preceding it, separated by a newline character.

```
sed -i '' "/\<\/plugins/ i \\
\            <plugin>\\
\                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>\\
\                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>\\
\                <executions>\\
\                    <execution>\\
\                        <id>attach-sources</id>\\
\                        <goals>\\
\                            <goal>jar</goal>\\
\                        </goals>\\
\                    </execution>\\
\                </executions>\\
\            </plugin>\\
" pom.xml
```

Comment: Love this concise answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This ll works from the first line.. For eg: If you want to insert from 3rd line of a file, replace "1i" to "3i".

```
sed -i '1i line1'\\n'line2'\\n'line3' 1.txt 

cat 1.txt

 line1
 line2
 line3
 Hai
```

Answer (score 1):

When the lines to be inserted are the result of some command "mycmd" (like `cat results.txt` or `printf "%s\n" line{1..3}`), you can do

```
sed -i 's/Line to insert after/r' <(cmd) file
or 
sed -i 's/Line to insert after/echo "&";cmd/e' file
```

The last command can be simple modified when you want to insert **before** some match.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i '/Line to insert after/ i\
Line one to insert\
second new line to insert\
third new line to insert' /etc/directory/somefile.txt
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain what your change does.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & Bash):

```
sed -i $'/Line to insert after/a\line1\\nline2\\nline3' file
```

Answer (score 0):

To be POSIX compliant and run in OS X, I used the following (single quoted line and empty line are for demonstration purposes):

```
sed -i "" "/[pattern]/i\\
line 1\\
line 2\\
\'line 3 with single quotes\`
\\
" <filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with Perl also

```
$ cat MeanwhileInHell.txt
Iran|XXXXXX|Iranian
Iraq|YYYYYY|Iraquian
Saudi|ZZZZZ|Saudi is a Rich Country
USA|AAAAAA|USA is United States of America.
India|IIII|India got freedom from British.
Scot|SSSSS|Canada Mexio.
$ perl -pe 'BEGIN {$x="Line one to insert\nLine 2\nLine3\n"} $_=$x.$_ if /USA/ ' MeanwhileInHell.txt
Iran|XXXXXX|Iranian
Iraq|YYYYYY|Iraquian
Saudi|ZZZZZ|Saudi is a Rich Country
Line one to insert
Line 2
Line3
USA|AAAAAA|USA is United States of America.
India|IIII|India got freedom from British.
Scot|SSSSS|Canada Mexio.
$
```