# Insert multiple lines in file before specified pattern

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Unable to add lines before a matching line if the content has new lines and this content is generated by a function

another alternative that looked good ([Insert multiple lines into a file after specified pattern using shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497246/insert-multiple-lines-into-a-file-after-specified-pattern-using-shell-script)) but it only appends "AFTER". I need "BEFORE"

put the xml content into add.txt then

sed '/4/r add.txt' $FILE

```sh
#/bin/sh

FILE=/tmp/sample.txt
form_xml_string()
{
  echo "<number value=\"11942\">"
  echo "  <string-attribute>\"hello\"</string-attribute>"
  echo "</number>"
}

create_file()
{
  if [ -e $FILE ]
  then
          echo "Removing file $FILE"
          rm $FILE
  fi

  i=1
  while [ $i -le 5 ]
  do
          echo "$i" >> $FILE
          i=$(( i+1 ))
   done
}

create_file
cat $FILE

# file sample.txt has numbers 1 to 5 in each line
# Now append the content from form_xml_string to line before 4
# command I tried
CONTENT=`form_xml_string`
echo "CONTENT is $CONTENT"
sed -i "/4/i $CONTENT" $FILE
cat $FILE
```

Expected output:

```
1
2
3
<number value="11942">
  <string-attribute>"hello"</string-attribute>
</number>
4
5
```

Actual output (or error):
sed: -e expression #1, char 31: unknown command: `<'

Comment: May be I'm missing something, but `sed -i "/4/i $CONTENT" $FILE` already does what you're trying to do (insert lines BEFORE a given matching pattern)...so what's the real question here?

Comment: Forgot to add "Actual output": This is: sed: -e expression #1, char 31: unknown command: `<'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's normal that you get that error, the syntax of your text is not compatibale with your sed command, allow me to elaborate:

- First, you have a lot of `/`s in your text, and `/` is the delimiter in`sed`, that confuses the command, which is why you get that error. So you should escape all `/` in the text you are using, by replacing them with `\\/` (The extra `\` is going to be interpreted by the shell).
- Second, in the man for `sed`, we can see this small line about `/i`:

> Insert text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a backslash

This means that you also need to add a `\` before every newline, in your example this means adding `\\` at the end of every `echo`.

**Edit:**

Thanks to [Toby Speight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4850040/toby-speight)'s comment, I noticed that I forgot completly about the possiblity of changing `sed`'s delimiter, which can make your life a lot easier, since you wouldn't have to add `\\` before every `/` in your text. To do this all you need is to change this line `sed -i "/4/i $CONTENT" $FILE` to, for example, this `sed -i "\\_4_i $CONTENT" $FILE`.

Here's how your script will become once you introduce these changes:

```
#! /bin/sh
FILE=/tmp/sample.txt
form_xml_string()
{
  echo "<number value=\"11942\">\\"
  echo "  <string-attribute>\"hello\"</string-attribute>\\"
  echo "</number>"
}

create_file()
{
  if [ -e $FILE ]
  then
          echo "Removing file $FILE"
          rm $FILE
  fi

  i=1
  while [ $i -le 5 ]
  do
          echo "$i" >> $FILE
          i=$(( i+1 ))
   done
}

create_file
cat $FILE

# file sample.txt has numbers 1 to 5 in each line
# Now append the content from form_xml_string to line before 4
# command I tried
CONTENT=`form_xml_string`
echo "CONTENT is $CONTENT"
sed -i "\\_4_i $CONTENT" $FILE
cat $FILE
```

Comment: Might be simpler just to use a different delimiter in the sed program.

Comment: Thank you Toby Speight and Steve!

Comment: Btw, forgot to ask one question, How did you know to use "_" as delimiter when the default delimiter is changed. Would any other symbol have worked?

Comment: Yes, most symbols would be fine you could use `,` or `:` or `|` or even `#`, I chose `_` cause it's a personal preference of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Use `e` instead of `r`.

From the Sed manual about the `e` command:

> Note that, unlike the r command, the output of the command will be printed immediately; the r command instead delays the output to the end of the current cycle.

The delay of the `r` command is the problem, that you can not output anything after it.

Example for the `e` command:

```
seq 0 9 | sed -e '/4/{
  h
  e cat add.xml
  g
}'
```

`h` copies the matching line into the hold space and `g` copies it back into the pattern space. By this it appears after the "add.xml" in the output.

Comment: I liked this approach too but since the above approach (delimter change) allows me to use function and avoid file, I prefer that. Thank you for suggesting this one.

Comment: looks like this approach wont work if write that cat line as  "e cat $ADD_FILE"

Comment: if I change sed -e ' to sed -e " ( from single quote to double quote), it works! :)