# Windows batch: Insert multiple lines into a remote Linux file at a specific location using PuTTY and sed

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, sed, putty

I want to insert multiple lines into a Linux file at a specific location.
But not from a Linux script, but remotely from a Windows batch file using PuTTY (with the plink command).

I looked into this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22497381

From that I created following Windows command that adds four "Hello" lines after "#SOMETAG" in "some.yml" file. This is working file:

```
plink -batch -l SomeUser -pw SomePwd SomeLinuxComputer sed '/#SOMETAG/a Hello1\nHello2\nHello3\nHello4' ./some.yml
```

Now I saw that there exists a nice syntax in this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51585664

If I use this command here directly in an Ubuntu bash, it works file:

```
sed '/#SOMETAG/r'<(\
  echo "Hello1";\
  echo "Hello2";\
  echo "Hello3";\
  echo "Hello4";\
) -- ./some.yml
```

But how can I use this from Windows batch using plink?

Following approach did NOT work:

```
plink -batch -l SomeUser -pw SomePwd SomeLinuxComputer sed '/#SOMETAG/r'<(\^
  echo "Hello1";\^
  echo "Hello2";\^
  echo "Hello3";\^
  echo "Hello4";\^
) -- ./some.yml
```

It produces the message "The system cannot find the file specified".

Even an easier version like this here produces the same error message:

```
plink -batch -l SomeUser -pw SomePwd SomeLinuxComputer sed '/#SOMETAG/r'<(echo "Hello") -- ./some.yml
```

Can anybody help me?

---

**EDIT 2019-08-29:**

It is possible to just split the single line version contained at the beginning of my question into multiple lines escaped with `^`:

```
plink -batch -l SomeUser -pw SomePwd SomeLinuxComputer sed '/#SOMETAG/a^
Hello1\n^
Hello2\n^
Hello3\n^
Hello4^
' ./some.yml
```

But it is not a perfect solution, because indenting the "Hello" lines would produce leading blanks in the output (which I don't want to have).
That's the reason why a solution based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51585664 would be nice.

After the hint from MartinPrikryl that I forgot to escape the `<`, I made some additional tests with escaped `<` character.

The sample that is just adding one Hello line is working fine now:

```
plink -batch -l SomeUser -pw SomePwd SomeLinuxComputer sed '/#SOMETAG/r'^<(echo "Hello") -- ./some.yml
```

But the other sample that is adding multiple Hello lines now produces the error "*bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'*":

```
plink -batch -l SomeUser -pw SomePwd SomeLinuxComputer sed '/#SOMETAG/r'^<(\^
  echo "Hello1";\^
  echo "Hello2";\^
  echo "Hello3";\^
  echo "Hello4";\^
) -- ./some.yml
```

Comment: At least the `<` is interpreted locally by Windows. You may need to escape it with `^` (not sure if it works though).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks, this is a good hint. This was clearly an error in my command. The easy version containing only one echo is working fine now with this fix, but the more complicated version contaning two echos on multiple lines now produces another error message:
`bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ')'`
`bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: Why do you put them to multiple lines?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Because I want to add six lines in the file.
I thought it would be better understandable instead of using one very long line.

Comment: OK, so can you try it first in a single line? And only once you make that working, try to make it readable?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The single line version is already contained at the beginning of my question.
I will update my question with a sample where this single line is just splitted into multiple lines escaped with `^` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider/Is it acceptable to use `-m` to provide the command?

```
plink -batch -l SomeUser -pw SomePwd SomeLinuxComputer -m command.txt
```

With `command.txt` being:

```
sed '/#SOMETAG/r' <(
  echo "Hello1"
  echo "Hello2"
  echo "Hello3"
  echo "Hello4"
) -- ./some.yml
```

If you do not want an additional separate file, you can generate the `command.txt` by your batch.

---

Yet another option is to provide the input by local commands (of the batch file), like:

```
(
    echo Hello1
    echo Hello2
    echo Hello3
    echo Hello4
) | plink -batch -l SomeUser -pw SomePwd SomeLinuxComputer "sed '/#SOMETAG/r' - ./some.yml"
```

Comment: That would also be a nice solution, but in my case I want to avoid having a separate `command.txt` file.

But if it's not possible to fix the error I mentioned in my question ("bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)' "), I would mark this answer here as accepted...

Comment: The last snippet unfortunately results in following error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 16: missing filename in r/R/w/W commands`.
Anyway I set this answer to "accepted", because it also contains the sample with the `-m` argument, which I think is the best solution.

Comment: I'm not getting that error. The `-` argument to `sed` should tell it to read stdin instead of a filename. Maybe you a have a diffrent version of `sed`.

Comment: If it would work, it would be my favorite solution. I am using sed on Ubuntu 19.04 and `sed --version` says that I am using `sed (GNU sed) 4.7`. Which version are you using?

Comment: I have "GNU sed version 4.2.1".

Answer (score 0):

you are specifying a relative path to the file but you can't know what the current directory (".") for the remote session is. Try specifying the complete path like "/home/me/some.yml"

greetings

Comment: No, the first plink command in my question works fine, even with relative path.