# add line to file in specific place in linux (bash)

Tags: linux, bash

I'm using linux buildroot os disto 2020.02.
and I have a conf file formated like so:

```
[section1]
key1 = val1
ke2 = val2

[section2]
key1 = val1
ke2 = val2
```

I would like to add the line "key3 = val3" to section1, it's important to add it after all the existing lines in the section, how can I do it?

I am also need to delete this line after.

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to do add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly do add the same your question and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I don't have any efforts to the solution. I have no idea how can I do it.

Comment: `echo "key3 = val3" | crudini --merge conf-file "section1"` / `crudini --del conf-file "section1" key3`

Comment: @jhnc Thanks. unfortunately, crudini is not supported on my board.

Comment: @matz_ch Is `ed` available

Comment: @Jetchisel ed is not available.

Comment: that's too bad :-(

Comment: I have found a solution for a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497246/insert-multiple-lines-into-a-file-after-specified-pattern-using-shell-script Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Jetchisel Yes... :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this command :
:g/ke2/  +1 s/$/key3 = val3/ | +1,$ d