# Substitute lines in file before pattern

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file `foo` I want to edit. I want to substitute all the lines of the file
before a certain pattern match `$node_(2)`

```
$node_(0) set X_ 46.188445620285734
$node_(0) set Y_ 400.0
# $ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(0) setdest 46.188445620285734 400.0 0.0"
$ns_ at 4.230260628522046 "$node_(0) setdest 140.0 400.0 11.073898626729083"
$ns_ at 12.70167232749509 "$node_(0) setdest 140.0 293.81155437971427 11.073898626728642"
# $ns_ at 22.290747430998636 "$node_(0) setdest 140.0 293.81155437971427 0.0"
$ns_ at 24.512130351924498 "$node_(0) setdest 140.0 121.22627768528247 11.143254728766196"
$node_(1) set X_ 284.3754249089888
$node_(1) set Y_ 400.0
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(1) setdest 358.5058741786957 400.0 10.938908248230844"
# $ns_ at 6.776768539190925 "$node_(1) setdest 358.5058741786957 400.0 0.0"
$ns_ at 8.52331532068547 "$node_(1) setdest 400.0 400.0 11.27995015881709"
$ns_ at 12.201888828288247 "$node_(1) setdest 400.0 341.4941258213043 11.279950158817115"
# $ns_ at 17.388602719303435 "$node_(1) setdest 400.0 341.4941258213043 0.0"
$ns_ at 22.22922653365822 "$node_(1) setdest 400.0 141.4941258213043 11.258336966410015"
$node_(2) set X_ 270.0 //so basically here is the pattern match
$node_(2) set Y_ 293.0222761518543
.
.
.
```

The file should then look like this

```
$node_(0) set X_ 10.0
$node_(0) set Y_ 10.0
$node_(1) set X_ 510.0
$node_(1) set Y_ 510.0
$node_(2) set X_ 270.0 //pattern and everything after it is left intact
$node_(2) set Y_ 293.0222761518543
.
.
.
```

I tried usind sed

```
sed -i -e '/$node_(0)/,/$node_(2)/c\$node_(0)\ set X_ 10.0 \n$node_(0) set Y_ 10.0\n$node_(1) set X_ 510.0\n$node_(1) set Y_ 510.0' foo
```

but it removes the first `$node_(2)` line completely. Also, the number of lines before `$node_(2)` is changing for every new `foo` file so I can't count lines to substitute every time.

Comment: `$` in a regex matches end of line, you want to use `\$` or `[$]` to match a literal dollar sign.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now. You want to delete all lines before the first one matching your pattern and replace it with hardcoded lines. I recommend you use the sed [`r` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-r-_0028read-file_0029-command) ("read file").

Comment: @BenjaminW. exacltly! I already know what I'm substituting them with. I'll have a look at the link you posted and see if I can make it work

Comment: @tripleee thanks for pointing that out. I'll modify the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '0,/$node_(2)/{//!d;s//text to add\n&/}' file
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. (Added a `-i` after `sed` to change the file)

Answer (score 2):

If I put the lines you want to insert into a separate file `replace`:

```
$node_(0) set X_ 10.0
$node_(0) set Y_ 10.0
$node_(1) set X_ 510.0
$node_(1) set Y_ 510.0
```

I can do this:

```
$ sed -n '/\$node_(2)/,$p' infile | cat replace -
$node_(0) set X_ 10.0
$node_(0) set Y_ 10.0
$node_(1) set X_ 510.0
$node_(1) set Y_ 510.0
$node_(2) set X_ 270.0 //so basically here is the pattern match
$node_(2) set Y_ 293.0222761518543
```

The sed command suppresses printing by default (`-n`), then prints all lines from the first match of `\$node_(2)` (escaping `$` not strictly necessary here, but always a good idea if you don't use it as end-of-line anchor) to the end of the file (`$` address).

The `cat` command then first prints your replacement file, then the output of the sed command.

Or with the [sed `r` ("read") command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-r-_0028read-file_0029-command) <sub>(hat tip to [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) for suggesting the use of `-e`)</sub>:

```
$ sed -n -e '1r replace' -e '/\$node_(2)/,$p' infile
$node_(0) set X_ 10.0
$node_(0) set Y_ 10.0
$node_(1) set X_ 510.0
$node_(1) set Y_ 510.0
$node_(2) set X_ 270.0 //so basically here is the pattern match
$node_(2) set Y_ 293.0222761518543
```

The commands are separated into multiple `-e` chunks as `r` is a bit picky about what it sees as the filename to read. It would break if `$node_(2)` appears on the very first line, but if that were the case, you could really just concatenate your files anyway.

Comment: This looks like you wanted to use `sed r` (like you mentioned in a comment) and then gave up. Like the `i` command, `r` is tricky, but try using multiple `-e` options, like `sed -n -e 1r\\ -e replace.txt -e '/\$node_(2)/$p' infile` (not sure about the backslashes after `r`?)

Comment: @tripleee I thought about using `r`, but wasn't immediately clear about reading just once, and I don't think you can actually do it with a non-GNU sed, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970124/sed-to-insert-on-first-match-only - and looking above, I see that SLePort has suggested a solution like that.

Answer (score 1):

Just invert the logic.

```
sed -n '1i \
$node_(0) set X_ 10.0\
$node_(0) set Y_ 10.0\
$node_(1) set X_ 510.0\
$node_(1) set Y_ 510.0
    /[$]node_(2)/,$p' file
```

The `1` is an address expression which selects the first line and `i` is a command to insert text. Alas, the `i` command is not completely standardized, so implementation details and syntax (especially for inserting multiple lines) differs between platforms. For legibility and portability, maybe switch to Perl:

```
perl -i -ne 'BEGIN { print <<__the_end_of_the_BEGIN__; }
\$node_(0) set X_ 10.0
\$node_(0) set Y_ 10.0
\$node_(1) set X_ 510.0
\$node_(1) set Y_ 510.0
__the_end_of_the_BEGIN__
    $p=1 if /^\$node_\(2\)/;
    print if $p;' file
```

You could write a very similar Awk script but that doesn't *portably* support in-place editing of the file like `sed -i`/`perl -i`.

Perl uses dollar signs as a sigil for scalar variables, so those have to be escaped to be printed literally, and the regular expression dialect is different (and vastly more powerful) than traditional `sed` or Awk, but the only difference here is that parentheses need to be backslashed or otherwise escaped.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend a multi-step process.
First, have the lines you want already in a file, such as `header.txt`.

Now, find line number of the last line you want to delete:

```
$ first=$( grep -n '^\$node_(2)' test.txt | head -1 | cut -d: -f1 )
$ last=$(( first -1 ))
```

Delete those lines from the file:

```
$ sed "1,${first}d" myfile.txt
```

Now, cat the two files into a temp file and rename the temp file:

```
$ cat header.txt myfile.txt > tmp$$  &&  mv tmp$$ myfile.txt
```

Comment: Using a regex to find the line number of a line so you can remove it in a different command is decidedly an anti-pattern. This is inefficient, especially if the files are big, but in any case, `sed` can delete lines by regex just fine.