# sed insert line after a match only once

Tags: shell, sed, text-processing

My /etc/sudoers file contain entries as below. Through `sed`, I want to insert a new entry for a new file after the first entry(filename can be anything) as below and save the file.

Now:

```
#
# Many Line before
#include /etc/sudoers.d/file1
#include /etc/sudoers.d/file2
#include /etc/sudoers.d/file3
#include /etc/sudoers.d/file4
#include /etc/sudoers.d/file5
#include /etc/sudoers.d/file6
# Many lines after
```

Goal:

```
#
# Many Line before
#include /etc/sudoers.d/file1
#include /etc/sudoers.d/newfile
#include /etc/sudoers.d/file2
#include /etc/sudoers.d/file3
#include /etc/sudoers.d/file4
#include /etc/sudoers.d/file5
#include /etc/sudoers.d/file6
# Many lines after
```

I tried like this but it inserts for each existing entries.

`sed  '/include \/etc\/sudoers.d/a #include /etc/sudoers.d/newfile' /etc/sudoers`

NOTE: I tried other answers to similar questions, but all are inserting new line for each match.

Comment: try adding `\/file1$` to the current search regex.. you could also use another delimiter like `\|regex|a ...` to avoid all the `\/` ... and probably won't make a difference, but you need `\.` to match `.` literally

Comment: Use `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d`. See `man 5 sudoers`.

Comment: @Sundeep file1 need not be there, it could be any name. But #include /etc/sudoers.d will be there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert line after first match using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559359/insert-line-after-first-match-using-sed)

Comment: @RaviSaroch I already referred it. It inserts for each occurrence.

Comment: @Cyrus My file does not contain #includedir /etc/sudoers.d. Policy it seems.

Comment: See: [sed to insert on first match only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9970124/3776858)

Comment: @itsraja, then I'd suggest `awk '1; !f && index($0, "#include /etc/sudoers.d/"){f=1; print "#include /etc/sudoers.d/newfile"}'`