# How do I insert conditional text before the first match?

Tags: awk, sed

```
sed "/^.*#location/n;/.*location/i 0000" myfile
```

Find a location that does not start with a comment and insert 0000 in front of it the first time it matches.

What did I do wrong?

I 4 hours try some answers from google, try combine, but nothing changed.

For example this: [sed to insert on first match only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970124/sed-to-insert-on-first-match-only)

I try add like this:

```
sed "0,/^.*#location/n;/.*location/i 0000" myfile
```

or this:

```
sed "/^.*#location/n;0,/.*location/i 0000" myfile
```

and this:

```
sed "/^.*#location/n;/.*location/i 0000\n&/0" myfile
```

Input:

```
server {

    #location /api/graphql {
    #       modsecurity off;
    #       proxy_pass http://10.1.0.4;
    #}

    location 123 {
        proxy_pass 123;
    }

    location / {
            modsecurity off;
            proxy_pass http://10.1.0.4;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
server {

    #location /api/graphql {
    #       modsecurity off;
    #       proxy_pass http://10.1.0.4;
    #}

    0000

    location 123 {
        proxy_pass 123;
    }

    location / {
            modsecurity off;
            proxy_pass http://10.1.0.4;
    }

}
```

Input:

```
server {

    #location /api/graphql {
    #       modsecurity off;
    #       proxy_pass http://10.1.0.4;
    #}

    location 73347347 {
        proxy_pass 123;
    }

    location 123 {
        proxy_pass 123;
    }

    location / {
            modsecurity off;
            proxy_pass http://10.1.0.4;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
server {

    #location /api/graphql {
    #       modsecurity off;
    #       proxy_pass http://10.1.0.4;
    #}

    0000

    location 73347347 {
        proxy_pass 123;
    }

    location 123 {
        proxy_pass 123;
    }

    location / {
            modsecurity off;
            proxy_pass http://10.1.0.4;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()`:

```
$ awk '!done && match($0,/^([[:space:]]*)location/,a){print a[1] "0000" ORS; done=1} 1' file
server {

    #location /api/graphql {
    #       modsecurity off;
    #       proxy_pass http://10.1.0.4;
    #}

    0000

    location 123 {
        proxy_pass 123;
    }

    location / {
            modsecurity off;
            proxy_pass http://10.1.0.4;
    }

}
```

or using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk '!done && match($0,/^([[:space:]]*)location/){new=$0; sub(/[^[:space:]].*/,"0000",new); print new ORS; done=1} 1' fileserver {

    #location /api/graphql {
    #       modsecurity off;
    #       proxy_pass http://10.1.0.4;
    #}

    0000

    location 123 {
        proxy_pass 123;
    }

    location / {
            modsecurity off;
            proxy_pass http://10.1.0.4;
    }

}
```

Regarding "What did I do wrong?" - sed's great for doing s/old/new/ on individual lines but for anything else, just use awk for clarity, simplicty, etc.

Comment: Good, i do this, thx u