# Replace first space with other string in file with Bash script

Tags: linux, bash

for example I have a string like "test test test " in a file.
I want to replace the first space with ' 1 ' to make it "test 1 test test test " .

I tried `sed -i "s/^\ /\ 1\ /g" text.txt` but it will change all spaces to ' 1 ', so I would like to know how to make it only happen on the first found?

Comment: This seems to be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `'g'` option (global replacement) like this:

```
sed 's/ / 1 /'
```

Comment: I want to replace first three. How to do that??

Comment: Input : ``` 1972 ?        00:25:05 python
21408 ?        00:05:31 python help.py
27518 ?        00:00:00 python insert\ node.py 
32690 ?        02:51:20 python monitor\ the\ database.py```
Output:
27518|?|00:00:00|python insert\ node.py 
32690|?|02:51:20|python monitor\ the\ database.py

Comment: @RaviShankerReddy: Unfortunately without formatting it is impossible to understand data. I suggest you post it as a separate question and you will get faster help.