# Sed insert before first match

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to insert a string in html before the first "<p" in the file, however I am having some difficulty.

```
thestring="<p>this is some sentence</p>"
sed -i "/<p/i${thestring}" somefile.html
```

"somefile.html" however contains multiple lines containing "<p" and the above inserts the string multiple times.

I have tried doing this:

```
sed -i "0,/<p/i${thestring}" somefile.html
```

or

```
sed -i "0,/<p/s//i${thestring}" somefile.html
```

but I'm getting no where.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this link may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two things you may consider :

1) use `s/.../.../` instead of `i`

2) special chars in your `thestring` which would conflict with sed's `s` separator. In your example the slash in`/p>`

this should work for your needs:

```
 sed  -i "0,/<p/ s_^_$thestring\n&_" file
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me - $thestring is substituted in before every line until the desired line, instead of just before the desired line.

Comment: @RobinGreen specify the exact range of lines `sed 2,4...` rather than `0,... `

Comment: @MaxPower The problem is you don't necessarily know the line numbers in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "${thestring}" | sed s'@<p>this is@blah blah <p>this is@'
```

If you want to get a specific instance of "

", just add a bit more context for the search.