# How to replace string with random line from text file multiple times

Tags: linux, bash, random, sed, shuffle

I have a script that is meant to rotate thru a file and replace the place holder {{su}} with a random line from a file, the place holder appears multiple times in a file and I need to it to be a randomized each time. Currently it replaces every placeholder with the same line.

```
#!/bin/bash

subject=$(shuf -n1 *.subjects)
    cat tmp.$file | sed -e "s/{{su}}/$subject/" > output.file
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use sed to replace only the first occurrence in a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file)

Comment: I have looked at this and although this is related to my question it covers a different problem and the solution is unrelated.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you've posted all of your code...where does `$file` come from?

Comment: I apologize, the file is in the same dir with named "*.subjects"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer has subtle flaws:

- if `{{su}}` appears several times on the same line, the *same* replacement is performed for each pattern `{{su}}` of that line,
- because `read` isn't used with `IFS=` and the `-r` switch, you'll get other nasty surprises: spaces are not going to be necessarily preserved, and you'll get backslash interpretations (but that's easy to fix),
- if the replacement string contains slashes or other funny characters, `sed` will be confused.

A method that works, but that involves reading the whole file in memory (it's only good for small files where you have a small number of `{{su}}`):

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$(< filename.txt )

while [[ $file = *'{{su}}'* ]]; do
    repl=$(shuf -n1 file.subjects)
    file=${file/'{{su}}'/"$repl"}
done
printf '%s\n' "$file"
```

For an approach similar to the accepted answer, i.e., reading line by line:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
    while [[ $line = *'{{su}}'* ]]; do
        repl=$(shuf -n1 file.subjects)
        line=${line/'{{su}}'/"$repl"}
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < filename.txt
```

Now about the way to select a random line: while `shuf` is fine, it's an external process and since it's going to be invoked many times (in a subshell), you might consider implementing something similar in Bash. If you have a limited amount of lines, you may consider slurping all the lines into an array and selecting randomly an entry from this array:

```
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t replacements < file.subjects
nb_repl=${#replacements[@]}

while IFS= read -r line; do
    while [[ $line = *'{{su}}'* ]]; do
        repl=${replacements[RANDOM%nb_repl]}
        line=${line/'{{su}}'/"$repl"}
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < filename.txt
```

This only works if you have a “small” number of lines in `file.subjects` (by small, understand less than 32767), and if you're not too worried about the distribution obtained by the modulo. There are very simple workarounds to fix this, though.

**Note.** You're using `shuf -n1 *.subjects`. It's an error to invoke `shuf` with several files (at least with my version of `shuf`). So if the glob `*.subjects` expands to more than one file, you'll get an error.

**Note.** If you don't want to run into an infinite loop, make sure that the replacements don't contain the `{{su}}` pattern!

Comment: Can I use the second approach to replace multiple strings? i.e. {{su}}, {{fr}}... so fourth?

Comment: @BigEarl: Sure! you can stack lines of the form `line=${line/'{{su}}'/"$repl_su"}`, `line=${line/'{{fr}}'/"$repl_fr"}`, etc. where the replacements `repl_su` and `repl_fr` are defined appropriately.

Comment: So would I use a wildcard? `while [[ $line = *'{{su}}'* ]]; do` to     `while [[ $line = *'{{*}}'* ]]; do` ?? or use sort of regex **OR** statement?   _Thank you for your assitance_

Comment: @BigEarl Oh sorry I didn't address this in my previous comment. Your solution is correct but might have some caveats (and infinite loops). Another safer one, to only focus on `{{su}}` and `{{fr}}` is to use extended globs: `while [[ $line = *'{{'@(su|fr)'}}'* ]]; do`.

Comment: @BigEarl: I guess safety is more important than efficiency: so you have 2 options: one is to use extended globs as I showed, the other one would be to use regular expressions: `[[ $line =~ '{{'(fr|su)'}}' ]]`. I did a very quick benchmark and it _seems_ that the extglob `[[ $line = *'{{'@(su|fr)'}}'* ]]` solution is faster.

Comment: Thank you for your time and assistance.  If you do not mind one more request. I was using a long line of `| sed` statemtets. That allowed me to use replacements inside of replacements. i.e.. One placeholder is `{{img_map}}` and in the replacement string is`{{ml}}` as long as i replace them in that order it will replace the `{{ml}}` inside `{{img_map}}`  When using the IFS it will only iterate over the line once correct?

Comment: @BigEarl: `IFS` has nothing to do with that. You can use nested replacements: `{{img_map}}`→`stuff {{ml}} more stuff`. The order is irrelevant, as long as, eventually, there are no patterns left in the string. The `IFS= read ...` reads the line from the file, then it's the inner loop `while [[ $line = ... ]]` that does all the replacements from that line.

Answer (score 1):

you need a loop. start by using `wc -l` to count the number of lines in `tmp.$file`.
Then loop count times, in each time perform the two lines of shell script you have.
So in each loop, you get a new subject and execute a new `sed`. The trick is to use the address,address format for the `sed` command to execute the replace against a single line at a time, passing in the loop counter for the address.

so something like (pseudo code here):

```
$count = $(wc -l tmp.$file)    
$i=1    
cp tmp.$file > output.file    
while $i < $count    
 subject = $(shuf -n1 *.subjects)    
 cat output.file | sed -e "$i,$is/{{su}}/$subject/" > output.file    
 $i=$i+1    
end while
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need to iterate line by line in your file and generate random string every iteration. It will check all lines for `{{su}}` pattern and if finds it will substitute it with random string from another file:

```
while read line
do
subject=$(shuf -n1 *.subjects)
sed -e "s/{{su}}/$subject/g" <<< "$line")
done <1.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, I turned it to a one liner and worked great.