# How do you replace the first line that of a match with sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I am currently trying to replace lines in the following file:

```
Music_location = /home/music
Music_location = /home/music
Pictures = /home/pictures
```

How do I only replace the first "/home/music"  without saying what line it is on?
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use sed to replace only the first occurrence in a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file)

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file

Answer (score 2):

Using awk you can do this:

```
awk '!p{sub(/\/home\/music/, "/foo/bar"); p=1} 1' file
Music_location = /foo/bar
Music_location = /home/music
Pictures = /home/pictures
```

Answer (score 1):

In sed:

```
sed '0,/home\/music/s_/home/music_/foo/bar_' foo.txt
```

This starts at line 0, stops when it finds /home/music, and then replaces the /home/music with /foo/bar. In the "s_/home/music_/foo/bar_" part, I have changed the normal delimiter, a slash, to an underscore, so that I may use slashes in my regular expression.

Comment: Make sure you drop a note about your use of `_` as alternate delimiters. Most will know, but the person you are helping might be left scratching his head.