# using sed command to replace xml tags

Tags: xml, shell, replace, sed

in a project I have an info.plist (xcode project) file, which is an xml file. I would like to add more properties to it using a shell script on the terminal.

What I need to add to it is the following:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.myapp.test</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>test-scheme</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

After doing some research I found that the way to do it is to use the `sed`.

I will use the `sed` command to replace the first occurrence of the `< dict >` tag, which is always in the info.plist file, with the above code (and re-add `< dict >` at the start of it so I don't break the structure.

With the help of [This Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9453461/887835), I put together the following command:

```
sed ‘0,/<dict>/{s/<dict>/<dict><key>CFBundleURLTypes<\/key><array><dict><key>CFBundleTypeRole<\/key><string>Viewer<\/string><key>CFBundleURLName<\/key><string>com.myapp.test<\/string><key>CFBundleURLSchemes<\/key><array><string>test-scheme<\/string><\/array><\/dict><\/array>/}’ info.plist
```

Theoretically, that command should replace the first occurrence of `< dict >' tag with itself + the text I want to add, without line breaks. I also skipped the /

However when I run it I get the following error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
```

What am I doing wrong? is there something I should do to make this work? I tried skipping all the < and > without success.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comments by JJoao I tried replacing sed ‘... ‘ with sed '...', now I get the following error:

```
sed: 1: "0,/<dict>/{s/<dict><key ...": unterminated substitute in regular expression
```

**EDIT2**

For more clarification, This is my desired output:

I have an xml file, that has the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>en</string>
        .........
    </dic>
</plist>
```

I would like to insert the xml section I specified at the start. So the output would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict><key>CFBundleURLTypes</key><array><dict><key>CFBundleTypeRole</key><string>Viewer</string><key>CFBundleURLName</key><string>com.myapp.test</string><key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key><array><string>test-scheme</string></array></dict></array>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>en</string>
        .........
    </dic>
</plist>
```

Or to write it in a cleaner way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                <string>Editor</string>
                <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
                <string>com.myapp.test</string>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>test-scheme</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>en</string>
        .........
    </dic>
</plist>
```

Comment: use `xsltproc` for that. `sed` is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: @hek2mgl although if you wait for a few more minutes I'm sure you will find a bunch of answers showing how to do this using sed!

Comment: @hek2mgl I will take a look at xsltproc hopefully it will work. Thank you. Hopefully I can also get an answer here, that would save me some time.

Comment: In your experiences, start by replacing `sed ‘... ‘` with `sed '...' `

Comment: @TomFenech You'll even find [Tetris written in sed](https://github.com/uuner/sedtris). Would you say `sed` is the right tool to write a computer game?

Comment: @JJoao thank you, now I get `sed: 1: "0,/<dict>/{s/<dict><key ...": unterminated substitute in regular expression`

Comment: @hek2mgl haha that's brilliant :) and no, nor was I implying that sed is the right tool here.

Comment: @TomFenech Yeah, I know. Just wanted to show you that. (In the hope you don't know it already). Happy playing! :)

Comment: @hek2mgl even if I don't find an answer for my question, I am happy that I found the sedtris :D awesome!

Comment: @Youssef you should edit your question to show us your desired output.

Comment: ...next, in your sed  replace your substitute separator `/` by `!` to be less confuse. Example ,   `sed  '0,/<dict>/{s!<dict>!<dict>newcontents!}' `

Comment: @JJoao thank you but I still get `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '<'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`perl -p` behaves like sed; `perl -p0` reads all lines of info.plist file

usage: `perl changedict info.plist`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p0

my $new='
        <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                <string>Editor</string>
                <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
                <string>com.myapp.test</string>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>test-scheme</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>';

s!<dict>!<dict>$new!;
```

**Update**: The previous version is writing to standard output;
You can redirect it to a newfile `perl changedict info.plist > newinfo.plist`.

If you need infile substitution, change the first line to

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -pi0
```

Comment: Thank you. The output is working correctly in the command prompt but it is NOT changing the info.plist file. How can I make it change the content of the info.plist file