# How to limit sed change to first set

Tags: sed

I have a text file that contains entries shown below.

```
tag1start
text1
text2
text3
text4
tag1end
..
..
tag1start
text5
text6
text7
text8
tag1end
```

I need to change entries only in the **first** set of tag1start tag1end

I have attempted using "range" but it affects both the sets. How do I limit it only to the first set ?

```
/tag1start/,/tag1end/c\
Some other text1\
Some other text2\
Some other text3\
Some other text4\
Some other text5\
Some other text6\
tag1end
```

Comment: Possibly related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/148451/352349

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '/tag1end/,$!{1,/tag1start/!s/\(.*\)/Some other \1\\/;}'
```

Roughly translated: In all *except* the part from tag1end to the last line (which, being greedy, is everything after the first tag1end), do the following: in all *except* the part from line 1 to tag1start, turn `foo` into `Some other foo\`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
$ sed '/tag1end/,${p;d}; /tag1start/,/tag1end/{s/^/Some other /}' file
Some other tag1start
Some other text1
Some other text2
Some other text3
Some other text4
tag1end
..
..
tag1start
text5
text6
text7
text8
tag1end
```

#### How it works

- `/tag1end/,${p;d}`

  For all lines in the range from the first line matching `tag1end` to the end, `$`, print the line as it is (`p`) and start over with the next line (`d`).
- `/tag1start/,/tag1end/{s/^/Some other /}`

  We only get to this command if we have not yet reached the first `tag1end`.  If we have not yet reached `tag1end` and we are in the range `/tag1start/,/tag1end/`, then the commands in curly braces are performed.  You can put whatever `sed` commands you like in those braces.