# Error while trying to modify a file with 'sed -i'

Tags: unix, sed

My original file:

```
nameserver 123.23.23.12
nameserver 10.0.1.13
```

I want to change it to:

```
nameserver 10.0.0.1
nameserver 10.0.1.13
```

command that I am using:

```
sed -i 's/nameserver*/nameserver 10.0.0.1/g' resolve.conf
```

Error that I am getting:

```
sed: -i may not be used with stdin
```

Also, when I use the below to test the output:

```
sed 's/nameserver*/nameserver 10.0.0.1/g' resolve.conf
```

I get:

```
nameserver 10.0.0.1 123.23.23.12
```

In second scenario, it is not replacing the complete line but just appending my replace text.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/nameserver*/nameserver 10.0.0.1/g' resolve.conf
```

matches just `nameserve` followed by zero or more occurrences of `r` - essentially, just `nameserver`.

If you want to replace everything after `nameserver`, use this pattern:

```
sed 's/nameserver.*/nameserver 10.0.0.1/g' resolve.conf
```

But that would end up substituting both the lines in your resolv.conf.  Why not just replace the IP address part?

To replace only the first occurrence, you can follow this post: [How to use sed to replace only the first occurrence in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file)

To solve the issue with `sed -i`, pass a zero length option to the `-i` option so that it bypasses the creation of a backup file:

```
sed -i '' ...
```

Comment: Hi, IP address part is dynamic. That can be anything

Comment: Tried: sed -i'' 's/nameserver.*/nameserver 10.0.0.1/g' resolve.conf. Still getting the same error. sed: -i may not be used with stdin

Comment: Try `sed -i ''` - with a space after `-i`.  I tried without that space on Mac OS and Ubuntu and it worked.  What OS are you on?

Comment: that worked!! Any clue on only replacing the first occurrence?

Comment: If you have GNU `sed`, you can follow the steps from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file

Comment: Ok. I will try it out.

Comment: BTW, even though the IP is dynamic doesn't prevent you from just finding and replacing it -- that's actually the whole point of regex; for example: sed  's/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/10.0.0.1/'