# How to use sed to replace only the first occurrence?

Tags: linux, unix, sed

***This is my command:***

```
sed -i -E  's/(<Connector port=)([a-zA-Z0-9"-])+/\1"VALUE10"/g' server.xm
```

When i execute this cAll occurrences have been replaced in the file.

How to use sed to replace only the first occurrence in my file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use sed to replace only the first occurrence in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the first occurrence in the file:

```
first=$( egrep -n 'Connector port=[a-zA-Z0-9"-]' server.xm | head -1 | cut -d: -f1 )
```

Then, replace on that line:

```
sed -i -E "${first}s/(<Connector port=)([a-zA-Z0-9\"-])+/\1\"VALUE10\"/g" server.xm
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use awk. With GNU awk for gensub() and inplace editing:

```
awk -i inplace '!f{$0=gensub(/(<Connector port=)[[:alnum:]"-]+/,"\\1\"VALUE10\"","g"); f=1} 1' server.xm
```