# How to change strings on multiple lines in a file with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have file that has the following lines in it in a file called test.txt;

```
volumes:
  data:
    driver: test
```

I want to change them to;

```
volumes:
  # data:
    # driver: test
```

But when I use the following command it seems to not work:

```
sed 's/  data:\n    driver: test/  # data:\n   # driver: test/' test.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to match a pattern that spans multiple lines.  `sed` tries to match the regex to each line.  Try using a separate pattern for each line:

```
sed 's/^  data:/  # data:/;s/^    driver: test/    # driver: test/' test.txt
```

There are two `s` commands, separated by a semicolon `;`. You seem to need to require a specific number of spaces (2 for the `data` line, 4 for `driver`), so I left that the same.  Notice the use of `^` to anchor the regex to the beginning of the line.

---

Suppose your input file **test.txt** is now:

```
volumes:
  data:
    driver: test
volumes:
  data:
    driver: test
```

To only replace the *first occurrence* of the `driver: test` pattern (but *all* occurrences of the `data:` pattern), try something like:

```
sed 's/^  data:/  # data:/;0,/^    driver: test/s//    # driver: test/' test.txt
```

This will only work with **GNU sed**.  The result is:

```
volumes:
  # data:
    # driver: test
volumes:
  # data:
    driver: test
```

To only match the *first occurrence* of both, try

```
sed '0,/^  data:/s//  # data:/;0,/^    driver: test/s//    # driver: test/' test.txt
```

which gives

```
volumes:
  # data:
    # driver: test
volumes:
  data:
    driver: test
```

See also [How to use sed to replace only the first occurrence in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file)

Comment: That work, well somewhat.  I neglected to mention that driver: test is mentioned multiple times.  when I use the above command, it changes all the instances of it.  I only need to make a change to the first one.

volumes:
  data:
    driver: test
  storage
    driver: test
changes to 
volumes:
  data:
   # driver: test
  storage
   # driver: test

Comment: That is a significant change to your question. For that, I'll refer you to [How to use sed to replace only the first occurrence in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file)