# sed: replace first instance only with string containing bash variable

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed, centos7

This is a bit of a follow-on from [How to use sed to replace only the first occurrence in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file/) but with a more targeted ask. Given a file

```
Peach: data/file1.txt
Apple: data/file2.txt
Pear: data/file3.txt
Apple: data/file4.txt
```

The goal is to replace only the first line containing Apple with a new line containing a fixed string (Banana) followed by a bash variable. In the new output, line 2 is now:

```
Banana: newdata/data.txt
```

Here is the most recent attempt...

```
BananaVariable=newdata
sed -i -E "0,|(Apple).*|{s|(Apple:).*|Banana: "$BananaVariable"/data.txt|}" filename
```

However, this produces the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unexpected  `,'
```

I think I need the double quotes around $BananaVariable to escape so that it can insert the actual string rather than "BananaVariable", but I think those double quotes are causing the problem. (OS is CentOS 7, sed is GNU version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man sed`:

```
/regexp/
       Match lines matching the regular expression regexp.

\cregexpc
       Match  lines  matching the regular expression regexp.  The c may
       be any character.
```

So in your original command replace the first two bars `|` with slash `/` (equivalently, replace the first `|` with `\|`):

```
sed -i -E "0,/(Apple).*/{s|(Apple:).*|Banana: $BananaVariable/data.txt|}" filename
```

You can also shorten the command:

```
sed -i -E "0,/^Apple/s|.*|Banana: $BananaVariable/data.txt|" filename
```

output:

```
Peach: data/file1.txt
Banana: newdata/data.txt
Pear: data/file3.txt
Apple: data/file4.txt
```

Comment: You should drop the double quotes around `$BananaVariable` as it renders the variable effectively unquoted.

Comment: @Sergio Your first suggestion works correctly and involves the fewest changes to the current code -- thanks! Your second suggestion is the most economic solution proposed (so far).

Answer (score 0):

It is easier with `awk`:

```
var='newdata/data.txt'
awk -v v="$var" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=": "}
!p && $1 == "Apple"{$1="Banana"; $2=v; p=1} 1' file
```

```
Peach: data/file1.txt
Banana: newdata/data.txt
Pear: data/file3.txt
Apple: data/file4.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i -e '0,/Apple/!b;//cBanana: '"$BananaVariable"'/data.txt' file
```

If a line is not between the front of the file until a line containing `Apple` print as normal. Otherwise change the line containing `Apple` to the required string using a variable.