# Mac Command to find a first occurrence of string and replace it?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

```
{
"service " : "namespace",
"name" : "test ",
"name" : "abc",
}
```

I need to replace the first occurrence of name as
"name" : "test 12-12-34 12:09"
and the value "12-12-34 12:09" is in some another variable that we can access using $date

Comment: you should try using `sed`

Comment: .. and show what you tried

Comment: sed "0,/^.*\"name\"\(.*\)\,$/{s/\(^.*\"name\".*\)\"\,$/\1raw\"\,/}" test.json > abc.json  this commad is working fine on linux but not working for Mac

Comment: @gogaz this works on linux but not on mac

Comment: @Shahaji That's not JSON. Why is the file called `test.json`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file

Comment: @chepner this is the JSON file and I am trying to replace the value of key "name" as I shown to above example

Comment: You're missing the commas between the key/value pairs, and while not strictly forbidden, why do you have duplicate `name` keys? In general, you can't assume any particular order for the keys in an object. How do you know the "first" name is the one that needs to change?

Comment: you should also use a real json parser (such as jq). sed is not a tool meant to parse json.

Comment: @chepner sorry I missed commas when posting this example, I have this document in my NoSQL DB and that is in this format which having multiple "name" keys I need to replace the first occurrence of the key named "name" value to new one. So I am trying to do this and I did that using sed command on Linux but I am not able to run the same command for mac terminal as it does not support some values for sed command.

Comment: @DTSCode I can use JSON parser such as jq as suggested by you but I think this is not a default command which comes with both Linux and mac terminal. I think we need to install it using some specific command for specific OS specific terminal.

Comment: It can also be bundled with your program. Sed is not a JSON parser, and you shouldn't expect it to act like one. If you used proper tools, it would probably work fine on both operating systems