# Gvim command to insert string in middle of the line

Tags: regex, sed

So I want a gvim or sed command which would insert a string (new_string) before the first match (//). For instance

```
Say the input is            --> hi hola //Comment
Then the output expected is --> hi hola new_string //Comment
```

So basically I want to add a string just before the first occurence of `//`. I tried the sed command

```
sed 's/\<\/\/\>/Really &/' file
```

However, this doesn't work for `//` substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\<` and `\>` are word boundaries, but `//` are non-word chars. `\<` expects the next char to be a word char, and right before there must be start of a line or a non-word char. `\>` expects the end of string or non-word char immediately to the right and a word char immediately on the left. Thus, there is no match.

Also, it is a good idea to use regex delimiters other than `/` if you are using backslashes in the pattern or RHS.

Use

```
sed 's,//,new_string &,' file > newfile
```

It will replace `//` with `new_string //` once per line. If there is a need to replace the first occurrence in a whole file, see [How to use sed to replace only the first occurrence in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file)