# Append a line after the first match only using sed

Tags: bash, sed, pattern-matching

I'm using sed and i have a file which contains

apple
orange
banana
orange

i want to insert "pear" after the 1st orange only . So the output should be something like this

apple
orange
pear
banana
orange

I used this sed option:

> sed -i '0,/orange/a pear' filename

but this gives me a output something like this:

apple
pear
orange
pear
banana
orange

Comment: With GNU sed: `sed -e '1,/orange/{/orange/a pear' -e '}' file`

Comment: sed -e s/orange/orange\\npear/ < file should work on any sed.

Comment: Please provide only the append option of sed not the substitution one

Comment: @AdityaKhowala Did the teacher provide any other instructions on this assignment besides the restriction to using only _append_?

Comment: @John1024 actually this is not the actual file i have been working on , and because of that i have a restriction of not using substitution.

Comment: @AdityaKhowala If you explain your restrictions more fully (including, for example, why you think _substitute_ won't work on the real file), you will likely get more and better answers.    Good luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use sed to replace only the first occurrence in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '0,/orange/!b;//a\pear' file
```

Focus on the range of lines from the start of the file `0` to the first occurrence of the string `orange` otherwise bail out. If the line contains the first occurrence of the string `orange`, append the string `pear`.

Comment: just a query , what is the purpose of backslash before pear

Answer (score 0):

Using Substitution

```
s/^orange$/&\npear/;tl;b;:l;{n;bl}
```

Using Append

```
/^orange$/ {
    a\
pear
    bl
}
b;:l;{n;bl}
```