# How to replace first occurrence with sed?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have file with many name: I want to replace only the first one

```
sed -i "s/\(name:\).*/\1 ${NEW_VALUE}/" ./myFile

Input
-  martin:
    name: Martin D'vloper
    job: Developer
    skills:
      - python
      - perl
      - pascal
-  tabitha:
    name: Tabitha Bitumen
    job: Developer
    skills:
      - lisp
      - fortran
      - erlang
```

output to change only the first name  Martin D'vloper

```
-  martin:
        name: NEW VALUE!!!
        job: Developer
        skills:
          - python
          - perl
          - pascal
    -  tabitha:
        name: Tabitha Bitumen
        job: Developer
        skills:
          - lisp
          - fortran
          - erlang
```

It changed all names

I saw something with different syntax

```
sed '0,/pattern/s/pattern/replacement/' filename
```

but I can't change sed to this because the dynamic value 
Could you advise me how to replace only the first one with my syntax ?

Comment: It will make our life easy if you could provide samples of input and expected output, kindly add them in your post and let us know then?

Comment: Updated with input and output

Comment: I deleted my answer (`sed -z "s/name:[^\n]*/name: $NEW_VALUE/"`) because this question is indeed a duplicate. My answer can now be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54650952/6770384).

Comment: If it's always line 2: `sed -r '2s/(name:).*/\1 NEW VALUE!!!/' file`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
sed -i "0,/name:/{s/name:.*/name: ${NEW_VALUE}/}" ./myFile
```

It finds the first occurrence of `name:` and then does the substitution, which is replace *'`name: followed by any characters`'* (.*** means any sequence of characters**) with  '*`name: ${NEW_VALUE}`*' where *`NEW_VALUE`* is your dynamical variable from your example.

From man sed

> 0,addr2
>
> Start out in "matched first address" state, until addr2 is found. This
>   is similar to 1,addr2, except that if addr2 matches the very first
>   line of input the 0,addr2 form will be at the end of its range,
>   whereas the 1,addr2 form will still be at the beginning of its range.
>   This works only when addr2 is a regular expression.

Comment: Could you explain it ?

Comment: why do we need the first /name/{ ?

Comment: it should be name: corrected it, it basically says find first name: in file and the do the substitution that is specified, added man excerpt in answer

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i "/\(name:\).*/{s//\1 ${NEW_VALUE}/;:a;n;ba}" ./myFile
```

Match on `name:`, substitute new value and then read and print the remainder of the file.

Or alternative:

```
sed -z -i 's/\(name:\).*/\1 '"${NEW_VALUE}"'/M' file
```

N.B. the `M` flag to the substitution command to restrict the `.*` within a line.

Comment: I have GNU sed version 4.2.1, and it doesn't have the -z option.

Comment: Explanation of 1st option: when the pattern "name:" followed by any number of characters in the line are found, save "name:" as the first sub-expression(`/\(name:\).*/`), then do these commands(`{`): substitute(`s`) whatever was matched(`//`) for the 1st sub-expression(`\1`) followed by a space and what's saved in the variable NEW_VALUE(`*space*${NEW_VALUE}/`) then(`;`) create label 'a' right here in this command(`:a`) then(`;`) print and go to the next line or exit if there aren't any more(`n`) then(`;`) branch back to label a(`ba`). End of commands for matched pattern(`}`).

Answer (score 2):

If you are ok with `awk` then please try following.

```
awk '/name/ && ++count==1{sub(/name:.*/,"name: NEW VALUE!!!")} 1'  Input_file
```

In case you have a shell variable and you want to add its value to `awk` code then try following.

```
val="new_vaue"
awk -v value="$val" '/name/ && ++count==1{sub(/name:.*/,"name: "value)} 1'  Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself then append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` to above code.

Comment: @user1365697, see my 2nd solution where you could substitute values by variable(from shell to awk)  and let me know if this helps.