# Sed - replace with variable first occurrence only

Tags: sed

I have a file app.spec with the string:

```
Version:  1.0.0
```

I want to replace 1.0.0 with the variable `version` e.g. `1.0.1`. 
The regex below which matches this but how can I replace only the first occurrence?

`sed -i -E "s/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/$version/" ./app.spec`

I tried but it didn't work.

```
sed -i -E "0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/$version/" ./app.spec
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use sed to replace only the first occurrence in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file)

Comment: in the second case, you forgot the substitute command.. should be `sed -i -E '0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ s//'"$version"'/'`

Comment: @DaemonPainter Fair comment.

Comment: @Sundeep, Thank you! your answer helped me see I had missed the substitute as well as how to pass the variable when in single quotes.

Comment: glad I could help, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables for further details wrt using shell variables