# Sed command replace the first occurrence in file

Tags: sed

I am trying find and replace the line one of the existing file, when I am running the below `sed` command it is replacing all the lines which have the matched string, but instead I want to change only one place inside the file.

```
sed -i 's/azure.com/test.com/' file_name
```

Actual file

```
server_name azure.com
server_name azure.com
```

Expected result

```
server_name test.com
server_name azure.com
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use sed to replace only the first occurrence in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with portable `sed` with a simple loop.

```
sed '/azure\.com/{
    s//test.com/
    :a
    n
    ba
}' file
```

When you see a match, substitute; then start a loop which simply consumes and prints the rest of the file.

This is significantly less obscure in Awk. If you have GNU Awk, you even have an `-i inplace` option which behaves like sed's `-i` option.

```
awk '/azure\.com/ && !p { sub(/azure.com/, "test.com"); p=1 }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -i "0,/ azure.com: /{s/ azure.com/ test.com/}" file_name
```

It will replace only the first occurrence of azure.com from the file.

Comment: remove the extra / :

Comment: No its not working

Comment: The `0` pattern is a GNU `sed` extension.

Comment: sed -i "0,/azure.com/test.com/g" file_name