# sed command to replace first occurrence in file is not working

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I am trying to replace first string occurrence in file. e.g. Trying to replace first **foo** with **linux**

sample.txt

```
Hi foo bar
This is again foo bar.
```

Command: `sed '0,/foo/s//linux/' sample.txt`

Actual output from above command (basically no change)

```
Hi foo bar
This is again foo bar.
```

My expected output is as below

```
Hi linux bar
This is again foo bar.
```

Could anyone please help here?

Comment: You are missing the `-i` flag, which replace the contents of the file

Comment: What is not working? replacement? or in-place edit?

Comment: It doesn't matter for now, whether to replace inline in the file or display it. My first focus is to get it to work.

Comment: if you look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/148451/5291015, you fill find that your attempt only works on GNU sed and not on the one provided native with MacOS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**/tmp/test.txt**

```
Hi foo bar!
This is again foo bar
```

Use the following [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) commando to replace only the **first** orrouance of the search-string;

```sh
sed -e '1 s/foo/linux/; t' -e '1,// s//linux/' /tmp/test.txt
```

**Result**:

```
Hi linux bar!
This is again foo bar
```

---

- [Terminal output + OSX version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7GCH.png)
- [Terminal output; first `foo` on 3th line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLsPh.png)

Comment: @Sundeep This wil also work if the first `foo` is not on the first line

Comment: sorry, misunderstood the command previously, this is a nice workaround!

Answer (score 3):

With any `awk` following may help:

```
awk '/foo/ && ++count==1{sub(/foo/,"linux")} 1' Input_file
```

With GNU `sed` if one has enough memory in box following may help:

```
sed -z 's/foo/linux/' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`

```
awk '!f && sub(/foo/, "linux"){f=1} 1' ip.txt
```

- `!f` will be *true* as uninitialized variables are falsey by default
- `sub(/foo/, "linux")` will replace first occurrence of `foo` and returns `1` - thus making `f=1` and subsequent `!f` to be always *false*
- `1` to print `$0`