# What is the global flag for in sed?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed

I've come to know the global (`/g`) flag to mean the action should take place globally in a file.

If I want to replace all instances of "hello world" with "goodbye space", I would add `/g` on the end of the statement.

That makes sense. However...

I was writing a `sed` replace command and noticed that even if I didn't include `/g` it would still replace all instances in a file. Below is the contents of my `.txt` file:

```
hello there
how is life
today is over
today is over
don't be sad
today is over
tomorrow is a new day
```

Now, I want to file all of these "today is over" lines and replace them with "tomorrow will begin". Therefore, I wrote the below code:

```
YOUR_FILE='testing.txt'
LINE="today is over"

sed -i "" "s/$LINE/tomorrow will begin/" $YOUR_FILE
```

Despite NOT including the global flag at the end, it still replaces all instances of `today is over` with `tomorrow will begin`.

Can someone explain this behavior to me as I haven't been able to find anything about it. Why does it replace all instances even when I omit the `/g` part at the end?

Alternatively, if I wanted to only remove the first instance, how would I go about specifying that?

I am doing this on a Mac.

Comment: To be able to replace only first match: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file

Comment: @anubhava thank you. Is there a way to find it without a range? So I can write a script without assuming it'll be on a specified line?

Comment: It can be easily done in BSD awk. A non-gnu `sed` is not the best tool for this.

Comment: @anubhava I'm starting to see that haha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The global flag allows sed to replace multiple matches *in the same line*.

```
$ echo 'world world' > somefile
$ sed 's/world/hello/' somefile
hello world
$ sed 's/world/hello/g' somefile
hello hello
```

Comment: I'm...I'm embarrassed. I will accept this answer when enough time has elapsed.

Comment: We all make mistakes.