# How to take first numbers and ignore the rest using sed

Tags: bash, shell

I have this line of code. The sed is taking 10 and 5. How can I extract 10 and ignore 5?

```
$ NUMBER=$(echo "The food is ready in 10mins and transport is coming in 5mins." | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g') ; echo $NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just removing everything that isn't a digit, so `5` is left.

Instead, use a capture group to capture the first number, and use that in the replacement.

```
sed 's/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

In the regular expression:

- `^` matches the beginning of the line
- `[^0-9]*` matches all non-digits at the beginning of the line
- `\(` and `\)` surround a capture group
- `[0-9]*` matches digits. These are captured in the group
- `.*` matches the rest of the line.

In the replacement:

- `\1` copies the part of the line that was matched by the capture group. These are the first set of digits on the line.

Comment: Can you explain the code to me please (:

Comment: Added a detailed explanation

Comment: Are regex and sed similar in terms of syntax?

Comment: `sed` uses regular expressions.

Comment: and if the text to match has multiple lines, how do I stop after the first match? Otherwise it keeps matching for example 31 31 31 31

Comment: @maiky See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file